# Normalization in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database-normalization

What is normalization in MySQL and in which case and how we need to use it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is Normalisation (or Normalization)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246701/what-is-normalisation-or-normalization)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

I try to attempt to explain normalization in layman terms here. First off, it is something that applies to relational database (Oracle, Access, MySQL) so it is not only for MySQL.

Normalisation is about making sure each table has the only minimal fields and to get rid of dependencies. Imagine you have an employee record, and each employee belongs to a department. If you store the department as a field along with the other data of the employee, you have a problem - what happens if a department is removed? You have to update all the department fields, and there's opportunity for error. And what if some employees does not have a department (newly assigned, perhaps?). Now there will be null values.

So the normalisation, in brief, is to avoid having fields that would be null, and making sure that the all the fields in the table only belong to one domain of data being described. For example, in the employee table, the fields could be id, name, social security number, but those three fields have nothing to do with the department. Only employee id describes which department the employee belongs to. So this implies that which department an employee is in should be in another table.

Here's a simple normalization process.

```
EMPLOYEE ( < employee_id >, name, social_security, department_name)
```

This is not normalized, as explained. A normalized form could look like

```
EMPLOYEE ( < employee_id >, name, social_security)
```

Here, the Employee table is only responsible for one set of data. So where do we store which department the employee belongs to? In another table

```
EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT ( < employee_id >, department_name )
```

This is not optimal. What if the department name changes? (it happens in the US government all the time). Hence it is better to do this

```
EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT ( < employee_id >, department_id )
DEPARTMENT ( < department_id >, department_name )
```

There are first normal form, second normal form and third normal form. But unless you are studying a DB course, I usually just go for the most normalized form I could understand.

Comment: "What if the department name changes?" has nothing to do with normalization. (Eg you contaradict your own "making sure each table has the only minimal fields and to get rid of dependencies".) Neither does replacing columns by ids generally. Clearly it has something to do with replacing a table by more tables, but that general notion is not normalization, rather normalization is an example of it. You are (sometimes & sometimes not) conflating the two.

Answer (score 17):

Normalization is not for MYSql only. Its a general database concept.

> Normalization is the process of
>   efficiently organizing data in a
>   database. There are two goals of the
>   normalization process: eliminating
>   redundant data (for example, storing
>   the same data in more than one table)
>   and ensuring data dependencies make
>   sense (only storing related data in a
>   table). Both of these are worthy goals
>   as they reduce the amount of space a
>   database consumes and ensure that data
>   is logically stored.

Normal forms in SQL are given below.

> First Normal form (1NF): A relation is
>   said to be in 1NF if it has only
>   single valued attributes, neither
>   repeating nor arrays are permitted.
>
> Second Normal Form (2NF): A relation
>   is said to be in 2NF if it is in 1NF
>   and every non key attribute is fully
>   functional dependent on the primary
>   key.
>
> Third Normal Form (3NF): We say that a
>   relation is in 3NF if it is in 2NF and
>   has no transitive dependencies.
>
> Boyce-Codd Normal Form (BCNF): A
>   relation is said to be in BCNF if and
>   only if every determinant in the
>   relation is a candidate key.
>
> Fourth Normal Form (4NF): A relation
>   is said to be in 4NF if it is in BCNF
>   and contains no multivalued dependency.
>
> Fifth Normal Form (5NF): A relation is
>   said to be in 5NF if and only if every
>   join dependency in relation is implied
>   by the candidate keys of relation.
>
> Domain-Key Normal Form (DKNF):  We say
>   that a relation is in DKNF if it is
>   free of all modification anomalies.
>   Insertion, Deletion, and update
>   anomalies come under modification
>   anomalies

Seel also

[Database Normalization Basics](http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm)

Comment: This is full of errors. There's no single notion of ["1NF"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40640962/3404097). PKs don't matter, CKs do. 2NF is when no prime attribute is partially functionally dependent on a CK. 3NF is when no prime attribute is transitively functionally dependent on a CK. BCNF is when every determiniant of a non-trivial FD is a superkey. 4NF is when all MVDs are implied by CKs. Every FD is accompanied by at least 2 MVDs. DKNF has nothing to do with the sequence of NFs involving lossless decomposition based on FDs & JDs up to 6NF.

Answer (score 3):

It's a technique for ensuring that your data remains consistent, by eliminating duplication.  So a database in which the same information is stored in more than one table is not *normalized*.

See the Wikipedia article on [Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

(It's a general technique for relational databases, not specific to MySQL.)

Answer (score 2):

While creating a database schema for your application, you need to make sure that you avoid any information being stored in more than one column across different tables.

As every table in your DB, identifies a significant entity in your application, a unique identifier is a must-have columns for them.

Now, while deciding the storage schema, various kinds of relationships are being identified between these entities (tables), viz-a-viz, one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-many.

1. For a one-to-one relationship (eg. A
   Student has a unique rank in the
   class), same table could be used to
   store columns (from both tables).
2. For a one-to-many relationship (eg.
   A semester can have multiple
   courses), a foreign key is being
   created in a parent table.
3. For a many-to-many relationship (eg.
   A Prof. attends to many students and
   vice-versa), a third table needs to
   be created (with primary key from
   both tables as a composite key), and
   related data of the both tables will
   be stored.

Once you attend to all these scenarios, your db-schema will be normalized to 4NF.

Answer (score 0):

> In the field of relational database
>   design, normalization is a systematic
>   way of ensuring that a database
>   structure is suitable for
>   general-purpose querying and free of
>   certain undesirable
>   characteristics—insertion, update, and
>   deletion anomalies—that could lead to
>   a loss of data integrity.[1] E.F.
>   Codd, the inventor of the relational
>   model, introduced the concept of
>   normalization and what we now know as
>   the first normal form in 1970.[2] Codd
>   went on to define the second and third
>   normal forms in 1971,[3] and Codd and
>   Raymond F. Boyce defined the
>   Boyce-Codd normal form in 1974.[4]
>   Higher normal forms were defined by
>   other theorists in subsequent years,
>   the most recent being the sixth normal
>   form introduced by Chris Date, Hugh
>   Darwen, and Nikos Lorentzos in
>   2002.[5]
>
> Informally, a relational database
>   table (the computerized representation
>   of a relation) is often described as
>   "normalized" if it is in the third
>   normal form (3NF).[6] Most 3NF tables
>   are free of insertion, update, and
>   deletion anomalies, i.e. in most cases
>   3NF tables adhere to BCNF, 4NF, and
>   5NF (but typically not 6NF).
>
> A standard piece of database design
>   guidance is that the designer should
>   create a fully normalized design;
>   selective denormalization can
>   subsequently be performed for
>   performance reasons.[7] However, some
>   modeling disciplines, such as the
>   dimensional modeling approach to data
>   warehouse design, explicitly recommend
>   non-normalized designs, i.e. designs
>   that in large part do not adhere to
>   3NF.[8]

**Edit:** Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: @Ali: If you're going to cut and paste from Wikipedia, please also provide a link to the source.