# Best database design for storing number of clicks, on each date for each ad

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql, model

I have a particular problem. I'm modeling an online advertising database system and I don't know what is the best solution for storing number of clicks on specific date for given ad in a database.

---

#### Short system exlpanation (requirements):

System is showing ads on different websites (ad_page). Each website (ad_page) can have many places for ads (ad_spot). Each ad must be active on only 1 spot for some period of time. Ads are constantly changing spots and pages.

For each ad, system must know:

- Every page and time where that ad was active
- Number of clicks on each day (optionaly on each page)

For each website (ad_page) system must know:

- Number of clicks on ads on whole website (not particular ad_spot)

---

Current (simplified) model I'm having: [LINK](http://s7.postimage.org/vqal4aqij/problem.png)

I know this probably isn't best solution but I can't figure out something better.

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: Because on each click (on the ad) I have to check if current date exists and if it does exists then I have to perform update (and increment clicks) on two tables.. If not then I have to perfom insert. And that seems like much work for operation that must be really fast because it's often performed.

Comment: Which two tables get incremented?

Comment: Sorry, 3 tables (ad_page_stats.clicks, ad_history.clicks and ad_stats.clicks). But now when I look at it maybe ad_page_stats and ad_stats aren't necessary because all the information can be found in ad_history with proper query.

Comment: i was wondering about that - could you simply collect clicks in one table and make summaries later on. 'ad_history' could be a stored proc or view.

Comment: So I put everything in ad_history and than call stored procedure to perform update or insert and collect all information when necessary.. Hmm, that seems right :)

Comment: If your data is being added at high speed (which it sounds like) don't bother updating - just add a new row. Do rollups later if you have to.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments:

1) [Normalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258743/normalization-in-mysql). You should not be storing identical data [ie: number of clicks] in multiple places because it complicates things and causes this exact issue. Create a separate table to track them once, and only once.

```
TABLE clicks
  ad_id INT PK
  date DATE PK
  clicks INT
```

2) [You don't necessarily need to pre-check if the date exists.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

```
INSERT INTO clicks (ad_id, date, numclicks) 
  VALUES (TODAY(), 123, 1)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clicks=clicks+1
```

Comment: Since the @IvanLučin tagged with PostgreSQL: PostgreSQL does not support "insert or update"/"upsert", in that DBMS it would still be necessary to do this in two steps.