# I want jobs matching with same skill_ids,location of the job_id parameter skill_id (jobid is parameter)

Tags: mysql

I have one table jobs with fields

```
job_id    skill_ids   location
   1       1,2,3        1, 3
   2        2, 3         2
   3        1, 4         4
```

I want jobs matching with same `skill_ids`,location of the `job_id` parameter `skill_id` (`job_id` is parameter)
`skill_ids` are comma separated so it should match at-least 2 skills

Comment: Normalize your data first, otherwise that'll be hard to do with acceptable performance.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your tables should follow [Normalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258743/normalization-in-mysql)

So the tables should be:

**Job**:

```
 job_id    job_name
   1         Job One
   2         Job Two
   3         Job Three
```

**Skills**:

```
 skill_id    skill_name
   1         Skill One
   2         Skill Two
   3         Skill Three
```

**Location**:

```
 location_id    location_name
   1         Location One
   2         Location Two
```

**Job_skill**

```
  job_id      skill_id
    1           1
    1           2
    1           3
    2           2
    2           3
```

Then you can do [Mysql Join](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/)

```
  SKILL_ID = 'Your desired SKILL ID';
  SELECT * FROM Job JOIN job_skill on job_skill.job_id = job.job_id WHERE job_skill.skill_id = SKILL_ID;
```

This is only for JOB and SKILL, you can work a little more to make it work with Locations table:

**Job_location**

```
  job_id      location_id
    1           1
    1           3
    2           2
    3           4
```