# Finding collaborations in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a database of people and projects.  How can I find the names of people who collaborated with a given person, and on how many projects?

For example, I want to find the collaborators of Jimmy from the database:

```
+----------+--------+
| project  | person |
+----------+--------+
| datamax  | Jimmy  |
| datamax  | Ashley |
| datamax  | Martin |
| cocoplus | Jimmy  |
| cocoplus | Ashley |
| glassbox | Jimmy  |
| glassbox | Martin |
| powerbin | Jimmy  |
| powerbin | Ashley |
+----------+--------+
```

The result would look something like this:

```
Jimmy's collaborations:
+--------+----------------+
| person | collaborations |
+--------+----------------+
| Ashley | 3              |
| Martin | 2              |
+--------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the table with itself, group by the `person` field:

```
SELECT u2.person, COUNT(u1.project) AS collaborations
FROM users u1
JOIN users u2 ON u2.project = u1.project
WHERE u1.person != u2.person AND u1.person = 'Jimmy'
GROUP BY u2.person;
```

The query selects the projects in which Jimmy participated from `u1`. The rows from `u2` are filtered by the rows from `u1`. Duplicate entries, where the users from both tables match, are filtered with `WHERE` clause. Finally, the result set is grouped by `person`, and the [`COUNT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) function calculates the number of rows per group.

**Performance**

Note, an index for `person` and `project` columns (or two separate indexes) will significantly improve performance of the query above. Specific index configuration depends on the table structure. Although, I think the following is quite enough *for a table with two `varchar` fields for `person` and `project`*, for instance:

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD INDEX `project` (`project`(10));
ALTER TABLE users ADD INDEX `person` (`person`(10));
```

**Normalization**

However, I would rather store persons and projects in separate tables with their numeric IDs. A third table could play the role of connector: `person_id - project_id`. In other words, I recommend [normalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258743/normalization-in-mysql). With normalized tables, you will not need to build bloated indexes for the text fields.

Normalized tables may look as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY(`id`),
  -- This index is needed, if you want to fetch users by names
  INDEX name (name(8))
);
CREATE TABLE projects (
  id int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
);
CREATE TABLE collaborations (
  project_id int unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  user_id int unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY(`project_id`, `user_id`)
);
```

The query for the normalized structures will look a little bit more complex:

```
-- In practice, the user ID is retrieved from the calling process
-- (such as POST/GET HTTP requests, for instance).
SET @user_id := (SELECT id FROM users WHERE name LIKE 'Jimmy');

SELECT u.name person, COUNT(p.id) collaborations
FROM collaborations c
JOIN collaborations c2 USING(project_id)
JOIN users u ON u.id = c2.user_id
JOIN projects p ON p.id = c2.project_id
WHERE c.user_id = @user_id AND c.user_id != c2.user_id
GROUP BY c2.user_id;
```

But it will be fast, and the space required for the indexes will be significantly smaller, especially for large data sets.

**Original answer**

To fetch the total number of projects for each person, use [`COUNT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) function with `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT person, COUNT(*) AS collaborations
FROM users
GROUP BY person;
```

Comment: This returns a table of people and collaboration count, but what does the count mean without specifying a person?  I'm looking for all the collaborators and their counts of a single person.

Comment: @Rachie, check out [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c92a8/1). I've updated the answer.