# Count occurrence of unique value in a row using SQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have a table like this:

```
ID | B1 | B2 | B3 | B4 | B5 |  
------------------------------------  
1  | N  | N  | N  | N  | N  |
2  | N  | Y  | N  | Y  | Y  |
3  | N  | N  | N  | N  | Y  |
```

I want a query that should return

```
ID | Count |  
------------
 1 |   5   |
 2 |   2   |
 3 |   4   |
```

Comment: Please share what have you tried

Comment: See normalisation

Comment: I tried the one which is used in counting rows. i.e SELECT count(B1+B2+B3+B4+B5) as Count from table.  @1000111

Answer (score -1):

Note that boolean expression in `MySQL` resolves into `0/1`.

`a = b returns 1 only if a is equal to b otherwise 0`

```
SELECT 
  ID,
  (
    (B1 = 'N')+
    (B2 = 'N')+
    (B3 = 'N')+
    (B4 = 'N')+
    (B5 = 'N')
  ) AS Count
FROM your_table
```

---

<kbd>[**SEE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c5fe8/1/0)</kbd>

---

**Suggestion:**

Better normalize your data.

See <kbd>[**Normalization in MySQL**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258743/normalization-in-mysql)</kbd>

Comment: what if i have more number of Bs. What is I have value upto B40?

Comment: Normalize your data. This is the best suggestion in this case.

Comment: How to normalize. Please elaborate. take a case where B goes upto 30. thank you.

Comment: Are there only two types ('Y','N')?

Comment: Yes, only 2 types