# When do the Normalization in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Im new to database design, so please just dont blast me.

Considering a standard workflow for the creation of  a good database, at which step of the design process should i insert the "Normalization phase" ?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Normalization in MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258743/normalization-in-mysql)

Comment: At the very beginning. Each table you add to your design should be normalized from the start

Comment: At the early stage of designing, check normalization documents

Comment: Suppose that i have created an ER Diagram and the next step is to optimize it. When i should insert the normalization ?

Comment: You should not create a de-normalised ER diagram.

Comment: What do you mean by "optimize an ER diagram"?