# MySQL WHERE clause with array contains key

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table where one of the columns contain arrays of values as varchar fields (strings).

Example: The column named 'categories' has a string value '1,2,3' in row 1, and a string value '4,5,6' in row 2.

I want to use a WHERE clause that allows me to select the row where the 'categories' field contains the key value 2 (i.e. the first row).

How can this be done with MySQL?

I guess this can be done with some sort of a pattern match workaround, but is there a cleaner way to do it similar to the 'IN array' statement? (maybe something that makes use of STRING_SPLIT)

P.S.: Not asking if it is a good practice. I am asking how to get it done.

Comment: you should normalize your database instead. Comma-separated values are hard to work with.

Comment: Do not store numbers in delimited strings.  That is not the SQL way.

Comment: @Strawberry No, the question was not answered. I did not ask if it was a good practice to use this type of approach. I was asking how to get it done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Find_in_set()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function.

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table_name 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('2', categories) > 0
```

**PS**: You should really avoid storing comma separated lists in a single field. String operation functions like `Find_in_set()` are inefficient. You should really look to [normalize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258743/normalization-in-mysql) your database structure instead.