# Mysql Select Like query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I am a beginner in SQL. I wanted to show all the rows that has 'P1' but my query not giving me my desired output I have table named 'tbl1' like this

```
tbl1

id          Name           Tag
8756        ADD            P2;P3;P10;P11;P12;P15
7861        Add1           P6;P4;P5;P2;P3;P1
7823        Place          P11;P12;P10;P8;P9;P6;P7;P4;P5;P2;P3
5567        Tun            P12;P10;P8;P9;P1;P6;
6789        lac            P3;
```

My query is like this

```
SELECT id,name,tag FROM tbl1 WHERE tag LIKE '%P1%'
```

but my output is like this

```
id          Name           Tag
8756        ADD            P2;P3;P10;P11;P12;P15
7861        Add1           P6;P4;P5;P2;P3;P1
7823        Place          P11;P12;P10;P8;P9;P6;P7;P4;P5;P2;P3
5567        Tun            P12;P10;P8;P9;P1;P6;
```

my desired output is only those who has p1 which should only be this two only. is it possible?

```
 id          Name           Tag
 7861        Add1           P6;P4;P5;P2;P3;P1
 5567        Tun            P12;P10;P8;P9;P1;P6;
```

Comment: You have the problem because poor database design. Storing multiple values in one field will cause you all sorts of problems later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your like is matching `P11` and `P12` etc as well as `P1`

You can do the following things, first look for `;P1;` rather than `P1`

Second, fix the edge cases (where the tag is first of last). something like:

```
SELECT id,name,tag FROM tbl1 WHERE concat(';',tag,';') LIKE '%;P1;%'
```

Comment: thank you for the help and well explained answer It is working you are great thank you very much I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

- Firstly, it is not a good practice to store multiple values as delimiter-separated string in a RDBMS. You should consider [normalizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258743/normalization-in-mysql) your data.
- However, in this case, you can utilize [`Find_in_set()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function, to look for a substring inside a comma-separated string.
- But, you have a semicolon-separated string instead. So, we can use [`Replace()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function to replace all the commas with semicolon, and use `Find_in_set()` afterwards.

Try the following instead:

```
SELECT id,name,tag 
FROM tbl1 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(REPLACE(tag, ';', ','), 'P1') > 0
```

Comment: thank you for the help I tried it it worked also thank you I really appreciate it

Comment: @kanashii happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Because you are looking for anything that contains P1, you are getting all other records as P10 contains P1. As your values are separated by `;`, you can check for anything that is like `%P1;%` or if P1 is the last value, `%P1`

```
SELECT id,name,tag FROM tbl1 WHERE tag LIKE '%P1;%' or tag like '%P1'
```

Comment: thank you for the effort and help I am really grateful i tried it also it worked you are great as well thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your table is presented with the occurrences P11 and P1 when executing the sample code that you raise.

LIKE '% P1%' is consistent for both labels.

I would use a regular expression in the SQL statement.

For the case that you are wanting to solve would be:

```
WHERE column1 regexp 'P1$';
```

- P1 matches the characters P1 literally (case sensitive)
- $ asserts position at the end of a line

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OR` operator to query rows with `P1`:

```
SELECT id,name,tag FROM tbl1 WHERE (tag LIKE '%P1;%' or tag LIKE '%P1');
```

Comment: thank you for the effort and help I am really grateful i tried it also it worked you are great as well thank you