# How can I alter my table to not get this error

Tags: mysql

When I alter my table, I get an error:

> 1118 - Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 8126. This includes storage overhead,
>   check the manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs

I've tried everything I could possibly think, please help.

```
ALTER TABLE property_rs_1
  ADD `LA3_PhoneNumber3Ext` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'LA3Agent Phone3 Extension',
  ADD `LA3_PhoneNumber4Desc` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'LA3AgentPhone4Description',
  ADD `LA3_PhoneNumber4CountryCodeId` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'LA3Agent Phone4 CountryId',
  ADD `LA3_PhoneNumber4` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'LA3Agent Phone4 Number',
  ADD `LA3_PhoneNumber4Ext` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'LA3Agent Phone4 Extension'
```

Comment: I think the error is very very clear about what you should do with your table structure

Comment: And it looks like your table design is definetely not normalized and should be changed.

Comment: Have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258743/normalization-in-mysql and other resources about how to design your tables.