# How can I use an SQL query's result for the WHERE clause of another query?

Tags: php, sql, database, metaprogramming

Okay, basically I have a table that contains statements like:

```
incident.client_category = 1
incident.client_category = 8
incident.severity = 1
etc.
```

I would like to use the contents from this table to generate other tables that fulfill the conditions expressed in this one. So I would need to make it something like

```
SELECT * FROM incident WHERE incident.client_category = 1
```

But the last part of the where has to come from the first table. Right now what I'm trying to do is something like

```
SELECT * FROM incident WHERE (SELECT condition FROM condition WHERE id = 1)
```

id = 1 stands for the condition's id. Right now I only want to work with ONE condition for testing purposes. Is there a way to achieve this? Because if there isn't, I might have to just parse the first query's results through PHP into my incident query.

Table schemas:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO!  What would the expected results be, for example, of the query you list that you'd like to use?  I suspect you would be able to SELECT from condition and LEFT JOIN incident onto it, to get the data you really want, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks! A left join wouldn't really work since incident.client_category is a number and condition has sql conditions such as the ones described above: "incident.client_category = 1"

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand your question.  eshirvana's answer below seems sufficient.  I just ran this on my own DB and it works great: `select id from myTable where id IN (select MAX(id) from myTable);`.  I guess maybe we're both confused because we're not sure how these tables tie together?

Comment: Maybe. Here, this is how my tables look:
[condition](https://prnt.sc/vhld5y)
[incident](https://prnt.sc/vhldq0)
Obviously incident has more columns but they don't really matter.
The idea is that I want to get the tables that fulfill the conditions within the condition table. Just getting one of them fulfilling a condition would be enough for me right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Engineering Suggestion - Normalize the DB***

Storing a WHERE clause, like `id = 10`,  in a field in a MySQL table, is not a good idea.  I recommend taking a look at [**MySQL Normalization**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1258743/2430549).  You shouldn't store `id = 10` as a varchar, but rather, you should store something like `OtherTableid`.  This allows you to use indices, to optimize your DB, and to get a ton of other features that you are deprived of by using fields as WHERE clauses.

*But sometimes we need a solution asap, and we can't re-engineer everything!  So let's take a look at making one...*

***Solution***

Here is a solution that will work even on very old, v. 5.0 versions of MySQL.  Set the variable using `SET`, prepare a statement using `PREPARE`, and execute it using `EXECUTE`.  Let's set our query into a variable...

```
SET @query = CONCAT(
     "SELECT * FROM incident WHERE ",
     (SELECT condition FROM condition WHERE id = 1)
);
```

I know for a fact that this should work, because the following definitely works for me on my system (which doesn't require building any new tables or schema changes)...

```
SET @query = CONCAT("SELECT id FROM myTable WHERE id = ", (SELECT MAX(id) FROM myTable));
```

If I `SELECT @query;`, I get: `SELECT id FROM myTable WHERE id = 1737901`.  Now, all we need to do is run this query!

```
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @query; 
EXECUTE stmt1; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

Here we use a [`prepare`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/prepare.html) to build the query, [`execute`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/execute.html) to execute it, and [`deallocate`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/deallocate-prepare.html) to be ready for the next prepared statement.  On my own example above, which can be tested by anyone without DB schema changes, I got good, positive results: `EXECUTE stmt1;` gives me...

> `| id | 1737901 |` .

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to achieve your goal by using what is called `dynamic sql`, be ware that this works only select from condition table returns only one record.

```
declare @SQLSTRING varchar(4000)
,  @condition VARCHAR(500) -- change the size to whatever condition column size is

SELECT @condition = condition
FROM
    condition
WHERE
    id = 1
 SET @SQLSTRING= 'SELECT  * FROM incident WHERE  ' + @condition
                
exec sp_executesql(@SQLSTRING)
```

Comment: Doesn't really work because incident.client_category is a number and the subquery throws a result like "incident.client_category =1"

Comment: @EmilioBlancoKobernyk Ok , now It's clear, check the updated answer

Comment: Your answer likely should work but I couldn't get it working because I have no clue how to use it on Navicat and my sql command line is using one out of 2 servers I got installed. The one it's using is the one that doesn't hold this database haha :( thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have also tagged the question with PHP, I would suggest using that.  Simply select the string from the condition table and use the result to build up a SQL query (as a string in PHP) including it.  Then run the second query.  Psudo-code (skipping over what library/framework you re using to call the db):

```
$query = "select condition from condition where id = :id";
$condition = callDbAndReturnString($query, $id);
$query = "select * from incident where " . $condition;
$result = callDb($query);
```

*However*, be very careful.  Where and how are you populating the possible values in the condition table?  Even how is your user choosing which one to use?  You run the risk of opening yourself up to a secondary SQL injection attack if you allow the user to generate values and store them there.  Since you are using the value from the condition table as a string, you cannot parametrise the query using it as you (hopefully!) normally would.  Depending on the queries you run and the possible values there as conditions, there might also be risk even if you just let them pick from a pre-built list.  I would seriously ask myself if this (saving parts of SQL queries as strings in another table) is the best approach.  But, if you decide it is, this should work.

Comment: I am aware of how this could be harmful. I even told my client about it but he's fine with that. I had an idea of how to do it through PHP but didn't want to bother with it as an SQL solution was what I was looking for. Thanks for your answer!