# How to update mysql column using array

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working with mysql, I have table "wp_notification" and here is currently strcture of table

```
id              UserId                PostId              status
1               s:1:"8";              26                  accept
```

In "UserId" column, i am saving Userid of users in "array" format using "serialize" function, but now i want to update( add one more user id in this column) this column
So how can i do this ? Is this possible with mysql query only ?

Comment: Why is it not `i:1:8`? Also, you can just run an update query on just that column.

Comment: @geertjanknapen: i have userId and with use of "serialize" function i saved into database now want to add "one or multiple" data/UserId in this column

Comment: Well `userId` should be an `array`, I guess. Unserialize userId, `array_push` the new userId, serialize array again, update in database.

Comment: @geertjanknapen:means new record should be like 

s:1:"8";, s:1:"9";

am i right ?

Comment: Why not just insert the userId 8 into that column? Why serialize the data?

Comment: _"new record should be like s:1:"8";, s:1:"9"; am i right "_ - no, because that is not a valid serialize value to begin with. The info, that this is supposed to be an _array_ of string values, is completely missing here.

Comment: @CBroe: then 1) which is valid serialize ? 
2) should i use serialize ?
3) if no then in which format/style should be use ?

Comment: 1) You can easily figure that out yourself, by _using_ `serialize` on such an array. 2) No. 3) Keyword is proper _normalization_.

Comment: @Amy as I said before, you need to serialize an array if you want to provide multiple userIds there. But you really should wonder why you would want to do this instead of just inserting 8

Comment: @geertjanknapen because there can be multiple id's ( 8 , 9 , 7 ...) , what should i do then ?

Comment: row:`| id: 1 | userId: 8 | postId: 26| status: accept |`

Another row: `| id: 2 | userId: 9 | postId: 26 | status: accept |`
@Amy

Comment: @geertjanknapen understand , Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to update the column. You can add one more user id in the future/current cells in that column.

It is worth noting however that using a "serialized" output string as an Id in a database is not a good solution. See [Normalization in MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258743/normalization-in-mysql) .

Comment: i want to insert "multiple userId" in column so what should i do ?

Comment: This is a good question. The answer is: You shouldn't do this in one table. You need to learn about 1TM relationships in databases and then implement it using multiple tables: [1TM relationships](https://medium.com/@emekadc/how-to-implement-one-to-one-one-to-many-and-many-to-many-relationships-when-designing-a-database-9da2de684710)

Comment: if i avoid serialize then can i save multipel id in one column ? if yes then how ?

Comment: @Amy You do not want to save multiple ids in one column. Add a new row for every user id you want to save

Comment: @brombeer: can i do this without new row ? can i save in single column ? if yes then how ?

Comment: @Amy You can do this without a new row. However you should not do this in one row.

Comment: @Amy Multiple people advised to _not_ store multiple ids in one column. Why would you want to do this? This kind of defeats the purpose of a relational database. If you really really want to do this (for reasons only you know) you create an array, serialize it and store it in that column.

Comment: @brombeer okay understand