# How can I filter some product(s) with multi keywords efficient?

Tags: sql, mysql

I use PHP as backend and MYSQL as DB.
Should I use PHP's array_filter instead of use multi LIKE in SQL query to filter keywords?

data structure in db:

```
Product_ID INT(6) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
Product_Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Product_Des VARCHAR(10240) NULL,
Product_Price FLOAT(20) NOT NULL,
Product_Brand_ID INT(6) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (Product_brand) REFERENCES brand(Brand_ID),
Product_keyword VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL,
Product_Catagory VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
```

the product's keyword is store as JSON in Product_keyword like that:

```
{
  keywords: ["test1", "test2"]
}
```

Now I want filter product with Brand_ID = 1 or 2 and keyword have "test2" and "test9"

the Brand_ID part I can use SQL "IN" , but I not sure how to do with keyword

follow is the sample date

[image]

How can I filter some product(s) with multi keywords efficient?

Comment: To do this efficiently - you should normalise your database properly and stop using JSON as a work around. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258743/normalization-in-mysql

Comment: I agree with @NigelRen, in this case it's better to have one to many/many to many relationships. That way your indexing and search performance would increase as well.

Comment: Related: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad) (just substitute "delimited list" for "JSON array" and it's the same scenario)

Comment: so I slould split this into 3 table? @NigelRen
product, keyword, and product-keywords?

Comment: @Ming514810 that would make a lot of sense, yes

Comment: but how can I indexing for keyword after I split into 3 table? @ADyson

Comment: You want to know how to add a database index? Or do you still want to know how to write the sql query for the filtering? Try to stick to one question at a time please, otherwise it gets muddled