# Maximum length of a table name in MySQL

Tags: mysql

What is the maximum length of a table name in MySQL?

Comment: As many have already pointed out, the limit is 64.  The link to the pertinent section of the MySQL 8.0 manual is https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-length.html

Answer (score 128, accepted):

64 characters according to [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-length.html).

Comment: Yep it's defined somewhere in the internal tables that MySQL uses to track schemas.

Comment: For a visual: `create table EmployeeRecordRecordHoldingTableForHoldingEmployeeRecordsAndStuf` is the longest name allowed.

Answer (score 94):

It's 64 characters. The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html) shows these limits:

```
Identifier    Maximum Length (characters)
Database      64
Table         64
Column        64
Index         64
Constraint    64
Stored Procedure or Function    64
Trigger       64
View          64
Alias         256 
Compound Statement Label    16
```

Answer (score 5):

Names for databases, tables, columns, and indexes can be up to 64 characters long. Alias names can be up to 256 characters long.

Answer (score 3):

Mysql Maximum length of characters for all identifier are **64 characters** except **Alias (256)** and **Compound Statement Lablel (16)**
Check the whole list here
[image]