# ajax mysql call, maximum length?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Second question in two days. Same script. In the while loop there is two rows that build two table cells. The first one that's not out commented is working and the result ends up where it suppose to be. The out commented one is not working and i can not see why.

I have checked the name of the column in the mysql table and that's correct. About 10 columns from the table works. But the last 9 don't. The only thing i can see is that the names of the mysql columns are longer. Can the names be too long?

The ajax call is not making an error. And when I make the Table border =1 i can se that there is a cell but nothing in it. When they are both not out commented the second cancels out the first. But on it's own the first give a result.

Any Ideas?

Sorry for bad grammar or if the solutions was to easy.

Any suggestions are welcome.

**getdata.inc.php:**

```
//Output results
if(!$facebook)
{
    mysql_close();
    echo json_encode('There was an error running the query: ' . mysql_error());
}
elseif(!mysql_num_rows($facebook))
{
    mysql_close();
    echo json_encode('No results returned');
}
else
{
    $output_string = '';
    $output_string .=  '<table border="0">';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($facebook))
    {

        $output_string .= '<tr>';
        $output_string .= '<td>'.$row['sombem_profiler_customers_first_name'].'</td>';
        //$output_string .= '<td>'.$row['sombem_profiler_customers_adress_sending_street'].'</td>';
        $output_string .= '</tr>';
    }
    $output_string .= '</table>';
}

mysql_close();
// This echo for jquery 
//$output_string = $_POST['personalNumber'];
echo json_encode($output_string);
?>
```

**ajax.js:**

```
function ajaxCall(){

var pnumber = document.getElementById('search-personalNumber').value;

$.ajax({
    url: 'db/getdata.inc.php',
    type:'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { personalNumber: pnumber },
    success: function(output_string){
        $('#result_table').append(output_string);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(xhr.status);
    alert(thrownError);
  }
});
}
```

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: Just a guess, but there might be a typo in: `sombem_profiler_customers_adress_sending_street` on the "address" part.

Comment: The `mysql_` extension is being deprecated. For a good reason, I see.

Comment: @cory well thats the name in the mysql-table. Will change that later but for now i whant the script to work. :)

Comment: @JanDvorak Okey, is there any way to solve my problem?

Comment: @Mike Thanks. This script will not be on the internet but more of company network. But will try and secure it later on in development.

Comment: The maximum column length is 64. So that's not the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868302/maximum-length-of-a-table-name-in-mysql

Try var_dump the problematic $row[...], and see that the value you're expecting made it out of the database alive.

Comment: How about this: `$output_string .= '<td>'.htmlspecialchars($row['sombem_profiler_customers_adress_sending_street']).'</td>';`

Comment: Or try this (to help you debug): `ob_start();
 var_dump($row);
 $result = ob_get_clean();

 $output_string .= '<td>'.htmlspecialchars($result).'</td>';`

Comment: It did not solve the problem but I did find it. The htmlspecialchars($row['sombem_profiler_customers_adress_sending_street'])‌​ got me thinking of special characters in the swedish language and when i changed all letters to a-z it worked. But the htmlspecialchars line still got no result when the swedish specific characters was in use.

Comment: ob_start(); var_dump($row); $result = ob_get_clean(); $output_string .= '<td>'.htmlspecialchars($result).'</td>'; also returned a blank table cell.

Comment: Is there anyway to go get these special character å, ä and ö ?

Comment: Why do you use `json` as `dataType` in your `$.ajax` if you're actually parsing the data in PHP script as HTML?

Comment: It's an old script I modified. Never changed that part. And Ajax is not my best skill. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the special characters that was the problem. I found this script on the internet.

```
function umlaute($text){ 
    $returnvalue=""; 
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($text);$i++){ 
        $teil=hexdec(rawurlencode(substr($text, $i, 1))); 
        if($teil<32||$teil>1114111){ 
            $returnvalue.=substr($text, $i, 1); 
        }else{ 
            $returnvalue.="&#".$teil.";"; 
        } 
    } 
    return $returnvalue; 
}
```

and

```
$output_string .= '<td>'.umlaute($row['comhem_profiler_customers_adress_sending_street']).'</td>';
```

This converted the charcters to html variants. Thanks for sending me on the right path. Cheers!