# Maximum length of a Column name in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am working with mysql and have a column name with length 70.
So, I am getting error which states that the column name is too long.
Now, I just want to know what is the maximum length of column name in mysql?

Comment: Here is the [first result from Google](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html) for the query "mysql maximum column name length"

Comment: How is this question "not constructive"? I wouldn't know how to edit it to fit the SO Q&A format..

Comment: @Niccolò I am also wondering that how this is not constructive. Arrrgg

Comment: @SeanBright in 2018, this question is the first result on google. Also your link is outdated as it refers to mysql 5.0.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Similar question is already answered [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868302/maximum-length-of-a-table-name-in-mysql)
Anyway,
Maximum allowed length of column name is 64 according to documentation : [Mysql Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html)

Answer (score 35):

The following table describes the maximum length for each type of identifier.

```
Identifier                      Maximum Length (characters)
Database                        64
Table                           64
Column                          64
Index                           64
Constraint                      64
Stored Procedure or Function    64
Trigger                         64
View                            64
Alias                           256 
Compound Statement Label        16
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html), the max length is 64

Answer (score 2):

64 Characters in MySQL 5.0

Ref : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html

Answer (score 1):

It's 64 characters max in current version - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html

Answer (score 1):

Per the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html), the maximum length for a column name is: 64 characters.

Answer (score 1):

it is 64 in MySQL 5.0, you can check documentation about [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html)