# How to increase maximum identifier name length?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, limits

Table names, Column names, Index names, etc...  In MySQL (and MariaDB) these have a maximum length of 64 characters.  How can I increase that?

Duplicate here: [Maximum length of a Column name in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16920001/maximum-length-of-a-column-name-in-mysql)

MySQL docs here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html

MariaDB docs here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/identifier-names/

Troublesome answer: Switch to PostgreSQL and [recompile](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).

Background: Column names prefixed with table names combined with table names prefixed with sub-project names.  Usually project names are short, but two just collided and at least one of them will get a bit longer.

Example:

```
/* One MySQL Instance for in-house applications called "MySQL" on port 3306.  
 * One MySQL schema (database / catalog) per application "intranet_website".
 * Several sub-project prefixes per application, example: "finance_"
 * Individual table-name: "invoice"
 * Specific column-name: "TotalAmount"  ****/
CREATE TABLE intranet_website.finance_invoice_tbl (
    -- ...
    finance_invoice_TotalAmount DECIMAL(20,2),  -- 27 chars
    -- ...
)
```

This may seem excessive, but consider [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html), or even just .Net.

```
com.companyname.intranetwebsite.finance.invoice.getTotalAmount() // 63 chars
IntranetWebsite.Finance.Invoice.GetTotalAmount() // 47 chars
```

Note: It isn't my choice to prefix columns with table names.  However, there are a few cases where this becomes marginally useful for joins without re-joins of the same table.  I know of at least one concrete instance where code writing SQL-code was much easier to implement due to these prefixes.

Comment: It's a hard limit, it cannot be increased. If it could be, the documentation you linked to in the question would indicate the configuration values to do so.

Comment: This is no answer to your question, but can't you create separate database per project and name it appropriately? This would take at least project names out of equation

Comment: You can do it only by downloading mysql source, modify the neccesary parts of the code, compile and make. (If you can :))

Comment: Perhaps the problem is [normalisation](http://www.w3schools.in/dbms/database-normalization)?

Comment: Just to be sure, do you mean development projects or projects represented in your database? _Because if you mean projects represented in a database, you probably shouldn't need separate tables for different projects._ Also, why are you prefixing all columns with table names when simply fully qualifying the column names (`table_name.column_name`) isn't any longer?

Comment: @Uueerdo this is business logic data, so for example "finance_" is one project.  "warehouse_" is another.  So I guess I'd say these are sub-components of the system.  It's been convention since before I worked on this system to prefix columns with table name for clarity and readability.

Comment: @DhruvSaxena I think we land somewhere between 2NF and 3NF.  This seems to give us enough control and performance without moving too far toward star schemas for what we're doing.  I fail to see how more tables is going to make the names shorter though.

Comment: @abeyaz I don't prefer a non-standard compile, but I'm not totally against it either.  However, I'm most concerned about the need to test a change like that thoroughly.  The PostgreSQL docs make it sound already fairly well tested on that platform.

Answer (score 6):

It probably cannot be done, as others have already suggested in comments.

However, **you should *not* need to do this.**

**Column names prefixed with table names** are completely unnecessary, since SQL offers the `tablename`**.**`columname` syntax that you can use to differentiate between columns.  Actually, most programmers I know would wholeheartedly agree that prefixing each column name with the name of the table to which it belongs would be *very annoying*.

**table names prefixed with project names** are also unnecessary, because that's what catalogs / schemas are for.  Also, most RDBMSes support the `catalogname`**.**`tablename` syntax.  If you have multiple projects that share tables, *and* your RDBMS does not support cross-catalog relations, then I would suggest that you have a project refactoring issue, or a choice-of-RDBMS issue, not a table naming issue.

<sub>Also, if you think 64 character identifiers are short, you should try Oracle. Oh, the fun you will have!</sub>

Comment: Column prefixes was a battle I fought coming on-board this project.  I lost.  This is a single application with almost 300 tables and about a dozen "sub-projects".  I actually pushed for sub-project prefixes, especially given the possibility of sharing a single database instance with other applications in the company.  I wanted schemas/catalogs used at a very high level.  One per application, with a few "shared" schemas, perhaps one per department.  Although, I suppose the catalogs themselves could use prefixes...  I still don't relish the idea of nearly 100 catalogs.

Comment: @ebyrob - Time to warm up your resume?

Comment: @RickJames If I jumped ship every time someone dictated a minor style guideline (annoying prefixes), I'd never get anything done.  More generally, it'd probably be my education that needs some attention.  Or if I'm just doing it wrong, HELP!

Comment: This seems to be worse that a "minor style" problem -- it seems like a show-stopper if it won't fit in the available space.  (I would not endeavor to try to recompile to increase the 64.  Think what will happen if when you upgrade!)

Comment: @RickJames We've decided to pick shorter project names where possible, so far this has been enough.  Just to be clear, you unquestionably feel that 64 characters is "enough" for any "single sub-identifier" like say .`companyname`. from a java classpath and no language (not just SQL) should need to support longer identifiers?  Or is SQL somehow special in needing a 64 character limit?  Is this the 80 columns of our age?

Comment: As @Mike Nakis says Schemas and catalogs already solve that problem and there's no need to go over 64 characters. What you need to do is to bring up the question again. I agree and feel you that migrating databases is hard, but when they're built from the very start to blow up in someone's face, that's pretty much the only thing you can do to prevent the possible apocalypse. During the migration period, I would suggest replacing original tables with federated table engine and point them to actual ones. That way, you won't have downtime in production and still retain data read/write capability.

Comment: I use Node.js ORM named Sequelize with a lot of joins and generates those alias names automatically to easily create fetched tree for me. Sometimes I run into this problem and it's very annoying that there is no some configuration to fix it.