# Can anyone explain me 1NF, 2NF, 3NF, BCNF rules with a proper example?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, database-normalization

This is a common interview question. I faced one interview where the interviewer gave me one table and asked me tell him which normal form the table is in? If it's in ##NF, then normalize it to the next NF?

I'm always get confused between these normal forms of database. 
Can anyone explain to me these normal forms with a proper example of how each NF is modeled into table so it will help in my next interview?

Comment: Here's a good link: http://www.phlonx.com/resources/nf3/

Comment: I was just reading about the Normalization the other day on SO. Here is a good link that attempts to explain upto 2NF : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331838/normalization-in-plain-english/2331885#2331885

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can someone please give an example of 1NF, 2NF and 3NF in plain english?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723998/can-someone-please-give-an-example-of-1nf-2nf-and-3nf-in-plain-english)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are database normal forms and can you give examples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723998/what-are-database-normal-forms-and-can-you-give-examples)

Answer (score 5):

Boyce Codd Normal Form is really the most important and also the easiest to explain: Every non-trivial determinant is a superkey (just remember "arrows out of superkeys"). The lesser normal forms are only worth mentioning because BCNF is not dependency-preserving in a few cases.

Examples of BCNF and 5NF by Hugh Darwen:

- [Database Design Issues: Part I](http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~hugh/CS252/RDB-fundamentals-8-design-I.pdf)
- [Database Design Issues: Part II](http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~hugh/CS252/RDB-fundamentals-9-design-II.pdf)

For more mathematical definitions (Abiteboul et al):

- [Foundations of Databases: The Logical Level](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201537710)