# Boyce-Codd Normal Form explain

Tags: database, set, rdbms, database-normalization, bcnf

Accoring to Boyce-Codd Normal Form Definition,

Reln R with FDs F is in BCNF if, for all X -> A  in F+
-A is subset of X   (called a trivial FD), or
-X is a superkey for R.

```
 “R is in BCNF if the only non-trivial FDs over R are key constraints.”

 If R in BCNF, then every field of every tuple records information that 
 cannot be inferred using FDs alone.
```

What I dont understand is the above two statements about normal form,

Can someone give me an example?

Thanks!

Comment: The quoted text is a mess. Find a textbook. If that's from a textbook, find another one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can anyone explain me 1NF, 2NF, 3NF, BCNF rules with a proper example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692350/can-anyone-explain-me-1nf-2nf-3nf-bcnf-rules-with-a-proper-example)

Answer (score 0):

Some Pre-requisite terms before I try to Explain:

•   ***Non-key attribute***: An attribute that is not part of any candidate key is known as non-key /non-prime attribute.

•   **Superkey**: A set of attributes within a table whose values can be used to uniquely identify a tuple. A candidate key is a minimal set of attributes necessary to identify a tuple; this is also called a minimal superkey.

Now, BCNF is the advance version of 3NF, stricter than 3NF.

A table is in BCNF if every functional dependency X → Y, **X** is the **super key** of the table.

```
Consider a relation : R(A,B,C,D)

The dependencies are:

A->BCD

BC->AD

D->B

So, Candidate keys(or minimal super keys) are A and BC.

But in dependency: D->B, D is not a superkey.

Hence it violates BCNF form.

We can break this relation into R1 and R2 as:
R1(A,D,C) and R2(D,B) to get BCNF.
```

Comment: You use "CK" before defining it. "Non-key" should be "non-prime" or "non-CK". "Minimal" needs to be explained. Not "if", "when". When every *non-trivial* FD .... Not "the super key" but "a superkey". "advance version" doesn't mean anything. PS Please don't use code blocks to highlight normal text. PS This doesn't answer the question, which asks what the quoted text is trying to say.