# Which normalization form is commonly used?

Tags: sql, database, normalization

In relational Databases, of course.

Comment: up to 3NF, after that it gets advanced.

Comment: 3NF is a fair balance between good design and practicality.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331838/normalization-in-plain-english for more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the reqquirment whcih normal form to use, Most of the people make use of 3NF.

But one thing is there as the normalization level increase joins will increase to get data from database server.