# Multi attributed database design confusion

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database

Hi dear community members
I need help on designing a simple database. It is a database of student and schools. Same schools have multiple students and one student can be affiliated with multiple schools. I am wondering what is the best way to do it.

Sample scenario: User john went BI school as high school and MIT as University, user harry went to MIT as university.

One approach we can have is: 
We can have a db table

**User Table**

```
+--------+-------+-----------+
| usr_id | name  | school_id |
+--------+-------+-----------+
|      7 | john  |         1 |
|      7 | john  |         2 |
|      6 | harry |         1 |
+--------+-------+-----------+
```

**School Table**

```
+-----------+-----------+
| school_id |   name    |
+-----------+-----------+
|         1 | MIT       |
|         2 | BI School |
+-----------+-----------+
```

And use school_id as a foreign key in user table.

Another approach is:

**User Table**

```
+--------+-------+
| usr_id | name  |
+--------+-------+
|      7 | john  |
|      7 | john  |
|      6 | harry |
+--------+-------+
```

**School Table**

```
+-----------+-----------+
| school_id |   name    |
+-----------+-----------+
|         1 | MIT       |
|         2 | BI School |
+-----------+-----------+
```

**Users to schools table**

```
+----+---------+-----------+
| id | user_id | school_id |
+----+---------+-----------+
|  1 |       7 |         1 |
|  2 |       7 |         2 |
|  3 |       6 |         1 |
+----+---------+-----------+
```

Which approach would be best? Is there any other approach we can try here.

Comment: I don't think there is any other more efficient way to implement a many-to-many relationship than the second approach that you have used. This is how most people do it.

Comment: The second approach is the best because it is in the 3rd normal form and it easier to update and change and it will scale better

Comment: Thanks Rachcha and Sam S for help. I'll go with second approach then.

Comment: Of note, you probably don't need a separate id for the user-to-schools table - use the composite id of the user and the school (which should generally be unique).

Answer (score 0):

Based on normalization rules you have a many to many relationship(one student can attend one or more school and one school can have one or more students) the second approach is the correct one.

More info here [StackOverflow - Normalization in Plain English](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331838/normalization-in-plain-english)