# How do i include multiple row reference in one row?

Tags: mysql, sql, row

I have table pizza. It includes fields like cost, id, name (of pizza), and ingredients. 
I also have table ingredients, with name of ingredient, and id. How to i put in table pizza ingedients for example 1,2,4,15, and be able to get that ingredients name from table ingredients?

```
Table Pizza:
id   name          cost    ingredients
1    Vegie Pizza   12,59   1,2

Table Ingredients
id   name
1    cheese
2    broccoli
3    pepperoni
```

I would like to get for egzample name and ingredients:

```
Vegie Piza - cheese, broccoli - 12,59
```

Or be able to order Vegie Pizza with pepperoni.

How do i connect this two tables in a way I described?

Comment: You might want to read [Normalization in plain English](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331838/normalization-in-plain-english/3329564#3329564) and update your table design.

Comment: @DCoder Than you so much, that is what I Was looking for!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

You should have a table `PizzaIngredients`, with one row per pizza and per ingredient in the table.  Someones, one doesn't have control over the data structure being used.  If so, there is a solution in MySQL:

```
select p.name, p.cost, group_concat(i.name)
from pizza p join
     ingredients i
     on find_in_set(i.id, p.ingredients) > 0
group by p.name, p.cost;
```

However, a junction/association table is a much better way to store such data in a relational database.

Answer (score 1):

First of all donot store relations as comma separated values instead use junction table to relate 2 entities for this see [*`Database Normalization`*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

For your current solution you need to use `find_in_set` in join condition

```
select p.id,group_concat(i.name) ingredients,p.cost
from 
Pizza p
join Ingredients i on(find_in_set(i.id,p.ingredients) > 0)
group by p.id
```

### [`Fiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4e980d/3)