# how to count values with using find_in_set?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, csv

In my db, uid is the autoincrement value indicates user ids and u_follow shows the user that follows other users with their uid seperated comma. i want to count that how many followers has each user. How can i do that ?

```
uid        u_follow
1          2,3
2          1,3
3          1,2
4          NULL
5          2,3,4
```

Comment: Are you able to do this in your script? If possible I would instead recommend normalizing the data.

Comment: what do u mean by normalizing the data ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246701/what-is-normalisation-or-normalization-why-is-it-important

Comment: Mr E's answer about sums it up. Take a look at that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store one value per column, otherwise you just can't do relational queries. See [this excellent discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246701/what-is-normalisation-or-normalization-why-is-it-important) for an introduction to database normalization.

**`users`**

```
uid
...
```

**`followers`**

```
uid u_follow
1   2
1   3
2   1
2   3
3   1
3   2
5   2
5   3
5   4
```

Then:

```
select u_follow, count(*) as num_followers from followers group by u_follow
```

If you want to include users with no followers do something like:

```
with a as (
  select u_follow, count(*) as num_followers
  from followers group by u_follow
)
select users.uid, coalesce(a.num_followers,0)
from users outer join a on users.uid = a.u_follow
```