# Table referenced by other tables having different PKs

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, foreign-keys

I would like to create a table called "NOTES". I was thinking this table would contain a "table_name" VARCHAR(100) which indicates what table put in the note, a "key" or multiple "key" columns representing the primary key values of the table that this note applies to and a "note" field VARCHAR(MAX). When other tables use this table they would supply THEIR primary key(s) and their "table_name" and get all the notes associated with the primary key(s) they supplied. The problem is that other tables might have 1, 2 or more PKs so I am looking for ideas on how I can design this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're suggesting sounds a little convoluted to me.  I would suggest something like this.

```
Notes
------
Id - PK
NoteTypeId - FK to NoteTypes.Id
NoteContent
```

```
NoteTypes
----------
Id - PK
Description - This could replace the "table_name" column you suggested
```

```
SomeOtherTable
--------------
Id - PK
...
Other Columns
...
NoteId - FK to Notes.Id
```

This would allow you to keep your data better normalized, but still get the relationships between data that you want.  Note that this assumes a 1:1 relationship between rows in your other tables and Notes.  If that relationship will be many to one, you'll need a cross table.

Have a look at this thread about database normalization

- [What is Normalisation (or Normalization)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246701/what-is-normalisation-or-normalization-why-is-it-important)

Additionally, you can check this resource to learn more about foreign keys

- http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting the other table name's and primary key's in this table, have the primary key of the NOTES table be NoteId. Create an FK in each other table that will make a note, and store the corresponding NoteId's in the other tables. Then you can simply join on NoteId from all of these other tables to the NOTES table.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your problem, you're attempting to "abstract" the auditing of multiple tables in a way that you might abstract a class in OOP.

While it's a great OOP design principle, it falls flat in databases for multiple reasons. Perhaps the largest single reason is that if you cannot envision it, neither will someone (even you) looking at it later have an easy time reassembling the data. Smaller that that though, is that while you tend to think of a table as a container and thus similar to an object, in reality they are implemented instances of this hypothetical container you are trying to put together and operate better if you treat them as such. By creating an audit table specific to a table or a subset of tables that share structural similarity and data similarity, you increase the performance of your database and you won't run in to strange trigger or select related issues later.

And you can't envision it not because you're not good at what you're doing, but rather, the structure is not conducive to database logging.

Instead, I would recommend that you create separate logging tables that manage the auditing of each table you want to audit or log. In fact, some fast google searches show many scripts already written to do much of this tasking for you: [Example of one such search](https://www.google.com/search?q=mssql%20script%20to%20automatically%20create%20audit%20tables)

You should create these individual tables and then if you want to be able to report on multiple table or even all tables at once, you can create a stored procedure (if you want to make queries based on criterion) or a view with an included SELECT statement that JOINs and/or UNIONs the tables you are interested in - in a fashion that makes sense to the report type. You'll still have to write new objects in to the view, but even with your original table design, you'd have to account for that.