# MS Access Combo Box Selections and Time Calculation

Tags: vba, ms-access

Hi currently i am making a Table with 21 Columns ("Task, Name, Time Taken") Each group, so total 7 groups.

Task combo consist of "WIP, HOLD, Quality Check"
Name combo consist of "Mark, John, Alex"
Time taken is a number field "only minutes" like 150, 200, 300 etc

At the end i have 3 columns which is for total time taken for "WIP, HOLD, Quality Check"

My Requirements:
a) When i select a Task (eg. WIP) auto the name should block with the user logged in "I have created a employee table with login form its working fine"

b) When the task selected as "WIP" and entered the "Time Taken" may be multipal times wit there groups. only the WIP total time should calculate and reflect on "TOTAL TIME TAKEN for WIP column"

Please help me ... it may be confusing but let me know if your unable to understand.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing doesn't sound normalized at all.  I'm not entirely clear on your situation but I believe you need to have two at least two tables.  If you don't know what normalization is then

[What is Normalisation (or Normalization)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246701/what-is-normalisation-or-normalization)

is a good place to start

As for the last 3 columns with the total time.  You shouldn't put that in a table.  Once you have a table you should always have a query total it up for you.

Comment: Hi Thanks for information... I can understand about normalisation but i feel my requirement is different, As 7 groups simultaneously in the same form.... (All employee does multitasking, and the work will be for a week or a month also, so when ever a person handels the file he will select the task and enter the time ... Hope you got that now – at the end only i have consulate how much time spend on WIP, HOLD, Quality Check...that the requirement

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your table should have 5 columns.  ID, Task, Name, TimeTaken, GroupName.  Unless you have a need to show 7 groups simultaneously on the same form?  You can filter the data at any time based on GroupName.

For part a, it sounds like your login form should be able to feed your Name combo?  Just set ComboName.SelectedValue to whatever your user's name is.

For part b, I just don't understand what you're asking.  Can you clarify?

Comment: Hi Thanks for your information...

Yes 7 groups simultaneously in the same form.... (All employee does multitasking, and the work will be for a week or a month also, so when ever a person handels the file he will select the task and enter the time ...

Hope you got that now ??