# Sql Syntax error regarding copy data from different databases

Tags: mysql, sql, select

i have a syntax error in this code, but i can't see where since i think that the code is right... i want to copy some column in the database named "w" **(table creaturecache)** and replace that data with the columns in the **"world"** database **(table creature_template)**

CODE:

```
UPDATE world.creature_template 
   SET name, `type`, family, rank, modelid2, modelid3, modelid4, Health_mod, movementId, IconName, KillCredit1, KillCredit2, type_flags, questItem1, questItem2, questItem3, questItem4, questItem5, questItem6
SELECT male_name1, `type`, family, rank, modelId2, modelId3, modelId4, HealthModifier, movementId, icon_name, killcredit1, killcredit2, type_flags, QuestItem1, QuestItem2, QuestItem3, QuestItem4, QuestItem5, QuestItem6
  FROM w.creaturecache where world.creature_template.entry = w.creaturecache.entry;
```

Comment: ps. At the moment the program says that the error is on line 2 (from type to movementId, i use Heidisql)

Comment: Yes, you have a syntax error. What is the syntax for UPDATE statements?

Comment: i found on google UPDATE table SET columns SELECT right_columns FROM right_database CONDITION

Comment: It would probably benefit your game for the long term if you'd properly normalize your tables.  What if a create has more than 6 quest items, or 4 modelIDs? See this post for starting points. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246701/what-is-normalisation-or-normalization

Answer (score 0):

Such a joined table update is built differently:

```
UPDATE world.creature_template a, w.creaturecache b
SET a.name = b.male_name1,
a.`type` = b.`type`,
...
a.questItem6 = b.QuestItem6
WHERE a.entry = b.entry
```