# fetch the comma separate field in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

My table id and skillid values are

```
      1=>3 
      2 =>5
      3 =>5,6,8
```

I have tried the query to fetch the value from my table

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE skillid IN ('3', '5');`

But i am getting only two rows, that was first and second row.

But i need the result three rows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which rows are you getting? Can you share the exact output for the above query as well as for ` SELECT * FROM mytable`?

Comment: post your table structure and sample data

Comment: the above values are the data in my table. For the first id's skillid value is 3 and second id's skillid value is 5 and third id's skillid value are 5,6,8.If i run the above query i am getting the id result 1 and 2 only... but i need all rows.

Comment: You can use like query.

Comment: with above query you will get only two row. may be you need to NORMALIZE your tables. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246701/what-is-normalisation-or-normalization

Comment: N O R M A L I Z A T I O N

Comment: No. i don't want multiple rows.. i need to the result in above condition. I am expecting the exact query..

Comment: @mangala: you don't want a solution that will work and looking for a workaround for a shitty designed schema? That's funny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check

SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE 5 IN (skillid) OR 3 IN (skillid);

Answer (score 2):

The '`IN`' comparison operator works like an equality operator. This:

```
expr IN ('3','5')
```

is equivalent to:

```
( expr = '3' OR expr = '5' )
```

That should be sufficient to explain why your query is not returning what you expect.

---

If your table has a character column that contains a comma separated list, like this:

```
id  skill_id_list
--  -------------
 1  3
 2  5
 3  5,6,8
```

Then one option, to search for a particular id value in the list is to make use of the MySQL `FIND_IN_SET` function. For example:

```
SELECT t.id
     , t.skill_id_list
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET('3', t.skill_id_list)
    OR FIND_IN_SET('5', t.skill_id_list)
```

The MySQL `FIND_IN_SET` function is documented here:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set

Of course, that's only one option. There are several other ways to get an equivalent result.

If there are no spaces in the `skill_id_list` column, then another option is to use a `LIKE` operator, but taking care to handle the edge cases.

There are four cases you would need to check for the id value appearing:

- as the only one in the list
- at the beginning of the list
- in the middle of the list
- at the end of the list

To explicitly handle those four cases, you could check each one, for example:

```
 WHERE skill_id_list LIKE '3'        -- only one in list
    OR skill_id_list LIKE '3,%'      -- beginning of list
    OR skill_id_list LIKE '%,3,%'    -- middle of list
    OR skill_id_list LIKE '%,3'      -- end of list
```

Or, another way to approach that is to turn all of those cases into the single "middle of the list" by just appending a comma to the beginning and end of the list, and then doing a single check, for example:

```
 WHERE CONCAT(',',skill_id_list,',') LIKE '%,3,%'
```

Note that spaces embedded in the list could cause a row not to match. The MySQL `REPLACE` function can be used to remove spaces, replacing all spaces with an empty string, something like this:

```
 WHERE CONCAT(',',REPLACE(skill_id_list,' ',''),',') LIKE '%,3,%'
```

---

**NOTE**

The preceding attempts to to answer the question you asked. The following addresses a fundamentally different (though closely related) issue, concerning the relational dataa model and normalization.

Repeating attributes in normalized relational model are represented in separate table. That's the normative relational model. We typically avoid storing comma separated lists, and instead implement a separate table to store the repeating attributes.

For example, if a `job` has multiple skills, we would typically create another table to hold the list of job skills:

```
CREATE TABLE job 
( id  INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
, description VARCHAR(10)
);

CREATE TABLE job_skill 
( job_id   INT NOT NULL COMMENT 'FK ref job.id'
, skill_id INT NOT NULL COMMENT ''
, PRIMARY KEY (job_id, skill_id)
, FOREIGN KEY job_skill_FK1 (job_id) REFERENCES job (id)
);
```

We'd represent the data in your model as five separate rows:

```
job_skill
job_id  skill_id
------  --------
1       3
2       5
3       5
3       6
3       8
```

That's the normative pattern.

To get back a list of job ids that require skills 3 or 5:

```
SELECT s.job_id
  FROM job_skill s
 WHERE s.skill_id in (3,5)
 GROUP BY j.job_id
```

To get back a list of job ids that require skills 3 and 5, there's several ways to do that, for example:

```
SELECT s.job_id
  FROM job_skill s
    ON s.job_id = t
 WHERE s.skill_id in (3,5)
 GROUP BY j.job_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT s.skill_id) = 2
```

If it's more convenient for your use case to get back a comma separated list as a string, you can use the GROUP_CONCAT aggregate function:

```
SELECT j.id AS job_id
     , GROUP_CONCAT(s.skill_id ORDER BY s.skill_id) AS skill_id_list
  FROM job j
  LEFT
  JOIN job_skill s
    ON s.job_id = j.id
 WHERE ...
 ORDER BY ...
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE skillid LIKE '3%' OR skillid LIKE '5%';</strike>

Definetly this is NOT the way to do it...

YOU SHOULD NORMALIZE your table to avoid this kind of problems

Comment: if i have multiple id like 1,2,3,4,5,24,100? and it will fetch for 15,13 ids also. I don't want such results. If search with the id 1,2 that result i neede

Comment: This will actually include values such as '13' and '51', not just '3' and '5'.

Comment: @Tommy: what if it's `1,2,3` value in another row?

Comment: @zerkms yep this is not an option definetly... He should normalize the table and do this well

Answer (score 0):

This is not good practice, you should normalize your table table, but `REGEXP`  would be helpful

Please try this way

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 
skillid REGEXP '[[:<:]]3[[:>:]]' OR skillid REGEXP '[[:<:]]5[[:>:]]'
```