# SQL Select columns with comparison

Tags: php, sql

I have a SQL table which have a column named `keywords`.

Table:

```
| id | keywords |

| 0 | music programming guitar |
```

Now i have an array like `$array = array("boat", "water", "music");`.

My target is to select all columns which have at least one of the things from the array in the `keywords`.

Sql-Query:

```
"SELECT * FROM table WHERE keywords IN ('".$array."')";
```

It returns nothing.

Comment: You should definitely normalize your database first, get rid of the whitespace separated values in your column keywords. Once that's done, your query will also work.

Comment: rid with commas? Like `music,programming,guitar` ?

Comment: No. Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246701/what-is-normalisation-or-normalization Basically, you don't store multiple distinct values like different keywords in one column at all, you use multiple tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach I am going to describe is highly not recommended.  The correct approach is to have a separate table with one row per `id` and `keyword`.  This is a junction table, and it would have rows like:

```
id       keyword
1        music
1        programming
1        guitar
```

This is the *right* way to store lists in a relational database.  Databases have this great data structure for lists.  It is called a table, not a string.

But, if you are really stuck with this situation, then you can hack your way to a solution. Presumably, performance is not an issue.

The hack is to format your list as a regular expression, and create the `where` clause as:

```
where keywords regexp 'boat|water|music'
```