# Show All Records For Given Field Filter In Access 2010 Table

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Hopefully this will make sense...I have a table in Access 2010 that contains a list of suppliers and their point of contacts at the supplier and where I work. The POCs vary in number, anywhere from 1-4 up to this point. The table is set up so each POC is on a separate line.

The supplier could have one contact but work could have three different contacts and vice versa.

What I want to happen is when I select a value from a combobox on a form, all the related POCs need to be shown instead of cycling through them one by one.

For example, Supplier1 has two POCs at their facility and we have three at our facility. I would like to have the combobox find Supplier1 in the table and then show all the contacts for that supplier (their facility and ours) in a textbox.

The user will be able to edit the contact information and, if it is not too difficult, would be able to add/delete a contact.

I'm sure a question similar to this one has been asked before, however I have been unable to word it correctly to find a solution through google searches/this website. I'm comfortable enough with VBA to use that if required but am by no means an expert. I am completely unfamiliar with SQL and would like to avoid going that direction if at all possible.

I have to be careful with any data I provide but will do what I can if you need to see the data or anything like that.

```
Supplier    Code    Part    Supplier Contact   Procurement Contact  QC Contact
Ajin        AKVN            Patrick                 Yong                 Jack   
Ajin        AKVN            Chase                   Yong                 Jack   
Autoliv     AMNP   Seatbelt Daryl                   James                Lewis  
Bosch       AG48            Hancheul                Kevin           
Carlex      AKJ5  QTR Glasses  Bob                  Joy                   Zack  
Continental ANKC            Jacob           
KSR       C03A05 Brake Pedal Jose                   Paul                 David
KSR       C03A05 Brake Pedal Jose                  Paul                  Gary
KSR      C03A05  Brake Pedal Jose                  Paul                  Steven
KSR      AG5Z   Accelerator Pedal Jack             Paul                  David
KSR      AG5Z   Accelerator Pedal Jack             Paul                  Gary
KSR     AG5Z    Accelerator Pedal Jack             Paul                 Steven
KSR     AG5Z    Accelerator Pedal Cory             Paul                 David
KSR     AG5Z    Accelerator Pedal Cory             Paul                 Gary
KSR     AG5Z    Accelerator Pedal Cory             Paul                 Steven
```

Comment: Please add your table(s) with some sample data. If suppliers and POCs are in one table, you need to split them.

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance on this but how do I the files on here? If it requires something along the lines of dropbox or similar program then I will not be able to due to network restrictions

Comment: @ColeStratton you can't post the files per se. You can paste your data into the question body (a representative subset) and format it so it looks decent/workable.

Comment: Table has been added in the best format I could get it

Comment: It looks like this should be two separate tables, one for your supplies, and one for the Point of Contacts. However, either way have you tried using a subform in datasheet view do display your POC's related tot he chosen supplier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table needs heavy normalization (see e.g. [What is Normalisation (or Normalization)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246701/what-is-normalisation-or-normalization) or http://r937.com/relational.html )

I would suggest (Note: I'm not sure about the Supplier/Code/Part relation) :

```
- tSupplier
SupplierID   SupplierName
1            Ajin
2            KSR

- tParts
PartID     SupplierID   Code      Part
1          1            AKVN
2          2            C03A05    Brake Pedal 

- tContactTypes
TypeID    Type
1         Supplier 
2         Procurement 
3         QC

- tContacts
ContactID  SupplierID  TypeID  ContactName
1          1           1       Patrick
2          1           1       Chase
3          1           2       Yong
4          1           3       Jack
```

and so on.
The first column of each table is the **primary key**, an autonumber field.
All other ID columns are **foreign keys**, linking to a parent table.

Now you can have a combobox for the Supplier, which gives the SupplierID.
With that, you can filter the Contacts and show them in a datasheet subform.
Either all in one table, with the ContactTypes as column, or in three subforms, each filtered by one ContactType.

To be able to add new contacts, use the `BeforeInsert` event to assign the current SupplierID.

Comment: Code is supposed to be unique to Supplier. I realize in the example I have above that is violated. Is there a work around to accomodate this?

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure if Code is a supplier code or a part code. Just move it to the table where it belongs. And I assumed that suppliers can have more than one Part, therefore Parts belong in a separate table.  To quote from the first link above, "normalization is basically just the common sense". Think about the objects/things/whatever you are storing: suppliers, parts, contact persons. These things determine the structure of your tables, and their relations.

Comment: In addition to this, I am having to take a daily report sent through Excel and import into this database. I can append the records to the end of the table no problem however setting up the relationship for this table is causing me issues. If I let Access add the primary key upon import would that fix the issue? I would be linking a supplier field in the import data to the Supplier table suggested above.

Comment: If the import data doesn't have a column that qualifies as primary key, then yes, let Access create an autonumber field as PK. I can't really tell you more without seeing the table.

Comment: The import table has 25 fields worth of data so posting it here would be too much. I let access add the primary key however, it still says the Relationship must be on the same number of fields with the same data types. Supplier field in import data is Text format. The supplier field in the import data will eventually be updated depending on what is currently in the field. If you really need to see the table then I will work on getting it posted here.

Comment: Only the relevant columns are needed, of course. But please post it in a new question.

Comment: I was able to find a way to get it to work. Thank you for your assistance.