# Adding Data to multiple tables from single form Access Database

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a continuous form that will filter a table based on a combobox in the form header. Everything is run through one form as of now, no subforms. I want the user to be allowed to edit existing records as well as add new records. The editing does not appear to be causing me any issues, it is trying to add new records.

I had asked the question below a while back and got everything normalized fine and dandy. To get all the information together in one place I used a query, however records cannot be edited through a query so I just made a table based on the results. I have tried to edit the data by way of subform when the subform was based on the query but that did not work. Have not tried since I created the table that contains the query results.

Basically the issue is I cannot add a record, like brand new supplier since the supplier does not exist in the tables already. I would need to add data to multiple tables (supplier, supplier code, contact info, all info from prev 3). Really the one not needing anything added to it is the contact type table.

I read somewhere it is bad structure to need something like this to happen but if everything needs normalization that seems to be contradictory.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/3877ce6a-34d9-4732-9af3-4c2704e50a62/adding-data-to-multiple-tables-using-one-form-in-access-2010?forum=accessdev

[Show All Records For Given Field Filter In Access 2010 Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32098889/show-all-records-for-given-field-filter-in-access-2010-table)

Something I have not considered before is an Update Query. Would that work for this situation? I've not used one before but am always willing to learn something new. Only thing is I'm not comfortable with SQL but will use it if necessary, have a preference to use VBA if anything.

**Edit**

```
SELECT tblSuppliers.Supplier, 
       tblSupplierCodes.[Supplier Code], 
       tblContactType.Type, 
       tblContactInfo.[Contact Name],  
       tblContactInfo.[Contact Email]

FROM (tblSuppliers INNER JOIN tblSupplierCodes ON 
     tblSuppliers.ID = tblSupplierCodes.[Supplier ID]) 
     INNER JOIN (tblContactType INNER JOIN tblContactInfo ON 
     tblContactType.TypeID = tblContactInfo.TypeID) ON 
     tblSuppliers.ID = tblContactInfo.SupplierID

WHERE (((tblSuppliers.Supplier)=[Forms]![frmContacts]![cboChooseSupplier])) OR ((([Forms]![frmContacts]![cboChooseSupplier]) Is Null))

ORDER BY tblContactType.Type, tblContactInfo.[Contact Name];
```

Answer (score 0):

> however records cannot be edited through a query

This is a misbelief. A query with well-formed inner joins is updateable. The "1" side of 1:n relations must be a primary key.

There are other possible causes for your query to be read-only, see http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html or http://www.fmsinc.com/Microsoftaccess/query/non-updateable/index.html

You can't have GROUP BY, DISTINCT, UNION or OUTER JOIN in your query.

If you don't find the reason, post your SQL so we can have a look.

Comment: Now that you mention it, most of the tables have an autonumber primary key so some links do not originate from the primary key all the time. That very well could be my issue. _Queries with multi-table joins that aren't on key fields_ Quote pulled from second link that I believe most identifies with the issue I am having

Comment: Please add some newlines to that SELECT string, so it is better readable. --- But nothing obvious stands out. Try removing one table at a time and check which table prevents the query from being updateable.

Comment: If I am trying to add a new record to an existing supplier for example, tblSuppler.Supplier, and both tblContactInfo fields create the issue. Not sure if that helps to narrow it down any

Comment: Hm, no, not really. I suggest you experiment some more. If all else fails, you could upload an "anonymized" version of your database to some file hoster.

Comment: I ended up using a form with subforms to add not already existing suppliers, will follow same general concept to add to existing suppliers