# Abstract databases design.

Tags: mysql, database

So I'm creating a web app with different user types that can come from different countries. Examples of the user types would be `company`, `staff` etc. Where a company would have a `company_name` field and staff would not.

In the `users` database I'm wondering if it's a good idea to implement a one table per column approach i.e for each user attribute there would be a table with a foreign key which would be the `user_id` and a `value` for the attribute value.

eg.
`users.company_name =
id(PK), | user_id(FK) | 'company_name'
1       |    1        |   company 1`

`users.email =
id(PK), | user_id(FK) | 'email'
1       |    1        |   user@email.com`

The same could be applied to an `address` database where different countries' addresses have different values.

Opinions?

Comment: i would say no.  please think about the queries you will need to write

Comment: no way. you might as well use a single eav table at this point

Comment: I would disagree with the eav table because there would be no way of setting the correct data types for differnet fields

Comment: I attempted to explain general database design. If you like, you can go through this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32190581/normalization-in-database/32517139#32517139

Answer (score 1):

The term you're looking for is "[The Party Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716549/what-are-the-principles-behind-and-benefits-of-the-party-model)"

You want to use Table Inheritance†, also known as [subtype/supertype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subtype+supertype?sort=votes&pageSize=15) relationships to model stuff like this.

An Individual is a concretion of an abstract Legal Party. An Organization (e.g. a Company) is also a concretion of an abstract Legal Party.

"Staff" is not a subtype of Legal Party. It's a relationship between a Company and an Individual. A company hasMany staffRelationships with individuals.

I recommend [Single Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html), as it's fast and simple. If you really don't like nulls, then go for [Class Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html).

```
create table parties (
  party_id int primary key,
  type smallint not null references party_types(party_type_id), --elided,
  individual_name text null,
  company_name text null,

  /* use check constraints for type vs individual/company values */
);
```

I'd go with PostgreSQL over MySQL (or MariaDB) if you're going to use Single Table Inheritance, as the latter do not support check constraints.

You can make `user` belongTo a `party`, or make party haveOne `user`.

† Which is different than PostgreSQL's Inheritance feature.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a single users table with `company_name` and `email` columns.

For addresses table, I'd start with something simple like this: id, address_line_1, address_line_2, city, state, country, zip.

Comment: The problem with these two table designs is each user doesn't have a `company_name`, likewise different countries have different `address` formats.

Comment: So what is the problem? Those fields can stay Null

Answer (score 0):

With this strategy you'll have to do a lot of joining tables to get a meaningful query result. As a result your performance will suffer and you have very ineffective use of storage.

You should at least combine columns that will typically be combined for a logical entity in your application. So if a 'company' differs from 'staff' in that it has extra columns, you would create a table 'users.company_properties'.