# What is the optimal way of setting up a database for a messaging/email application?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, data-structures

I am currently trying to create an email style web app to allow users of my site to contact one another. I have created an SQL table for this, which has the following headings:

- id
- senderID
- recipientID
- timestamp
- message
- read (Boolean to record whether message has been read by recipient)
- starred (Boolean to record whether message has been starred by recipient)
- archived (Boolean to record whether message has been archived by recipient)
- deleted (Boolean to record whether message has been deleted by recipient)
- convoID

I have started to now realise that this table is insufficient. For example, if the conversation has been starred by a user, this does not tell me which of the 2 users has starred the convo, etc.

Can anyone suggest a way to avoid the above issue, and maybe suggest a better database structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend split your table into two, let's call them "message" and "star". So, they are:

```
message
-------
id
sender_id
recipient_id
timestamp
read
archived
deleted
convo_id
parent_id

star
----
message_id
user_id
timestamp
```

As you can see, I added parent_id into message. If you don't need hierarchical structure - you may kick this column. A star table gives possibility to enhance starring feature. Who knows, maybe in future all users may put a star, not only participants of conversation.

In addition, there is a nice articles about DB normalization. It will really helps you to build well-organized DB structure:
[What is Normalisation (or Normalization)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246701/what-is-normalisation-or-normalization)
http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php
http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/definition/normalization

Answer (score 0):

depend on your application and how many users you will have.
About the starred, archived and other stuff where both users can do things, you can use an `enumeration` or simply a couple of values. Not just a boolean.
Or you can split every read with a `senderRead` and `recipentRead`