# User-Role-Permission based database design

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-design

I want to design database for a Java web app in which a **user** can have a particular **role** and that **role** can have permission to access specific tabs based on **PERMISSION_CODE**

So, I have created three tables like:

```
 CREATE TABLE "PAWAN"."USERS_TABLE" 
    (   
    "ID" NUMBER(4,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "USER_NAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "PASSWORD" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "FIRST_NAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "LAST_NAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "CREATED_DATE" DATE DEFAULT sysdate, 
    "ROLE_ID_FK" NUMBER(4,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    PRIMARY KEY ("ID") ENABLE,
    CONSTRAINT "FK_ROLE_ID" FOREIGN KEY ("ROLE_ID_FK")
    REFERENCES "PAWAN"."USER_ROLES" ("ID") ENABLE
    );     

  CREATE TABLE "PAWAN"."USER_ROLES" 
    (   
    "ID" NUMBER(4,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ROLE_TYPE" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ROLE_DESCRIPTION" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CREATED_DATE" DATE DEFAULT sysdate, 
    "PERMISSION_ID_FK" NUMBER(4,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    PRIMARY KEY ("ID") ENABLE, 
    CONSTRAINT "PERMISSION_ID" FOREIGN KEY ("PERMISSION_ID_FK")
    REFERENCES "PAWAN"."PERMISSIONS_TABLES" ("ID") ENABLE
    );   


CREATE TABLE "PAWAN"."PERMISSIONS_TABLE" 
   (    
    "ID" NUMBER(4,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "PERMISSION_CODE" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "PERMISSION_DESC" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CREATED_DATE" DATE DEFAULT sysdate, 
     PRIMARY KEY ("ID") ENABLE
   );
```

Now, I need a fourth table which contains list of tabs that belongs to particular **PERMISSION_CODE** of **PERMISSIONS_TABLE**

What's is coming in my mind is to have a table having columns like

- PERMISSION_CODE
- TAB1 (Yes/No)
- TAB2 (Yes/No) and so on..

But this is not a good design, because every time a new tab is created, I have to add one more column. 
One alternative is to have structure like:

- PERMISSION_CODE
- TAB_NAME

But this way no. of rows will be more.

Is there any way to store tabs in a array like structure? Can any one suggest me an better approach?

Comment: "But this way no. of rows will be more." - why is that a problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> But this way no. of rows will be more.

Databases are good in managing a huge number of rows, million of rows is not a problem.

> Is there any way to store tabs in a array like structure?

**No no no - don't go that way.**
This breaks the [Database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) rules, esspecially the [first normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) thast says:

> First normal form (1NF) is a property of a relation in a relational
>   database. A relation is in first normal form if and only if the domain
>   of **each attribute contains only atomic (indivisible) values**, and the
>   value of each attribute **contains only a single value** from that domain.

This aproach (storing many values in one colum) seems attractive at first glance, but some day you will fall into trobles when someone will ask you for a query "give me all users who have access to tab `TAB-233`". 
Some other disadvantages of this approach:

1. each query must parse the array
2. RDBMS can't use indexes on multivalue columns, each query like `SELECT ... WHERE tab='TAB-333'` must always use a full table scan and is not scaleable.
3. how to update or delete ? Instead of simple `UPDATE ... WHERE` or `DELETE .. WHERE ...` each update command must unpack the array, change/delete one value and pack and store changed array back to the column.
4. You can't use any referential integrity on this column.

Please see an aswer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246701/what-is-normalisation-or-normalization) for more details.

---

In your model there are the following relationships:

1. The user **has** roles
2. The role **has** permission codes
3. The permission code **has** tabs

---

But there are rather n:n relationships, not 1:n, because I can see that:

1. The role **has** many users (because several users can have the same role)
2. The permission code **has** many roles (because several roles can have the same permission code)
3. The tab **has** many permission codes (because several permission codes can have the same tab)

---

So in this model there would be the following tables:

- USERS(id, user_name, password, etc)
- ROLES(id, role_name, etc )
- PERMISSION_CODES( id, code_name, etc )
- TABS( id, tab_name, etc )
- USER_ROLES( user_id, role_id )
- ROLE_PERMISSIONS( user_id, perrmission_id )
- PERMISSION_TABS( permission_id, tb_id )

Comment: Is `ROLE_PERMISSIONS( user_id, permission_id )` meant to be `( role_id, permission_id )`?