# Remove item from list in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex

I've a MySQL database in which there is a table named `customers`. Inside this table there is a field named `preferences`, which content is a list of names, single or composite.

Table customers:

```
id   name   preferences
---------------------------------
1    John   pears,tomato sauce,bread
2    Rose   carrot cake, salad
```

I can easily add an new entry in the field preferences doing something like:

```
UPDATE `customers` 
  SET preferences = CONCAT(preferences,',oranges') 
WHERE id=2
```

But now, I wonder if there is an easy way to remove a known item in that list, which does not mean, read back the registry entry, processing it using PHP and saving it again.

I was trying to use `REGEX_REPLACE` unsuccessfully, since the word can be at the beginning, middle or end. So I didn't succeed to write a proper expression for substituting the results. Anyway Regular expressions, is probably not the right way to go.

Thanks

Comment: Best answer would be to normalize column preferences

Comment: What do you mean to normalize?

Comment: list strictly comma separated?

Comment: You may want to read up on [normal form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246701/what-is-normalisation-or-normalization). It will cause you a lot less headaches down the stretch.

Comment: Yes, the list is strictly comma separated: Comma won't be used in the words

Comment: Could not post it as a "answer" because the question was marked as duplicate before i could post but take a look to this https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/21o7s3GeerqY4ifWEz1G9n/3 if you can't normalize.. Normalizing also would require the application code to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Update `customers`
    set preferences = TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM TRIM(BOTH 'oranges' FROM TRIM(REPLACE(CONCAT(" "',oranges'" "),' ,oranges ',''))));
```

It will delete ',oranges'. If there is no space before and after `,oranges` it would not delete it. As you can see it is not a `Regex` anymore. Also `TRIM(BOTH 'oranges'` will delete 'oranges' from first and last place in the string.

[**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/HLOT32090)

Comment: I know, but this is not valid, since there could be composite words like: ",oranges (pre-cutted)", so you would be deleting half of the term.

Comment: I have edited my answer, please have a look

Comment: @Carles - that is the **exact** reason why you should normalize your DB. Split up your DB into 3 tables: `customers`, `preferences`, `customer_preferences` and then link them via foreign keys. It sounds difficult but in reality, it is simple as pie.

Comment: Thanks @AndreiSuvorkov, I will try that, but anyway I think the right way to go is normalization.

Comment: MySQL REGEXP doesn't have the lookahead nor lookbehind features.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte good point, anyway Carles will do normalization, which is in this case more preferable

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov - Sorry, but I have to down vote this because it cannot work.  MySQL's `REPLACE` does not work with regular expressions.

Comment: @RickJames thank you for your feedback, I have edited my answer, and I think found a good solution for it

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov - That's better.  Now what about `oranges` being the first or last in the commalist?

Comment: @RickJames I think now it works perfect. Please have a look.

Comment: @Carles I have edited my answer and I think it is good solution now, probably you can use it as well. Please have a look on it.