# How to find a Value in MS Access "Table 2" based on "a field value" & "a field name" on "Table 1"

Tags: ms-access, field, lookup

I've 2 Tables, as shown in the attached example
I want to retrieve the data from table 2 based on two records, "size" as 1st field value & "category" as a field name. 
In Excel, it is easy by using Vlookup & match functions, but I want it In Access.
As an example: From Table 1 at 3rd record , "size"=3 & "category"=D, then "item 3" value shall be retrieved from Table 2 with two conditions: "Size" = 3 & field name ="D" i. e. "30".
Thank you.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G94Bu.jpg) ;
[Actual Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llz7g.jpg)

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* I'm not entirely clear on what you're asking, but **the Access table equivalent of VLOOKUP is [`DLOOKUP`](https://support.office.com/article/dlookup-function-8896cb03-e31f-45d1-86db-bed10dca5937)**.  Also, check out the [tour] (you'll earn your first badge!). There's other good tips in "[ask]" and how to create a [mcve], as well as this [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) from the sites' top user.  You can always [edit] your questions to add more information if necessary.

Comment: Thank you, I already added an example.

Comment: Your data in table 2 isn't normalised, meaning that any working query would have to be "dynamic" SQL which is not easy to manage or a preferred method. If you normalised your data this would be simple  .  Have a read of this to better understand - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246701/what-is-normalisation-or-normalization

Comment: Actually, this is an example but the original data for table 2 is only numbers. I already changed the example. Thank you

Comment: If that really is your data, then you can calculate the value based on the letter, as it's a fixed off-set ? E.g `NumberVal:  Asc([Category])-54+((IIf([Size]>1,([Size]-1)*8,0)))`  Except your data seems to miss the value of 35 out ?

Comment: Unfortunately, the actual data is completely different - see the attached actual data. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The following function solved my problem to find a value on a table based on a value in a row & column name**
I think it may require some tuning on the code to be faster.

```
Function MatchColumn(row As Single, column As String) As Single
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim fld As DAO.Field
Dim Pos As Integer ' coulmn position
Set db = CurrentDb
Set tdf = db.TableDefs("Table 2")
Set rs = tdf.OpenRecordset

For Each fld In tdf.Fields
 If fld.Name <> column Then Else Exit For
Next
Pos = fld.OrdinalPosition

If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
 Do While Not rs.Fields(0).Value = row
 rs.MoveNext
Loop
MatchColumn = rs.Fields(Pos).Value

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set qdf = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
End If
End Function
```