# Mysql IN function

Tags: mysql, sql, null

class_table

```
+----+-------+--------------+
| id |teac_id| student_id   |
+----+-------+--------------+
| 1  | 1     | 1,2,3,4      |
+----+-------+--------------+
```

student_mark

```
+----+----------+--------+
| id |student_id| marks  |
+----+----------+--------+
| 1  | 1        | 12     |
+----+----------+--------+
| 2  | 2        | 80     |
+----+----------+--------+
| 3  | 3        | 20     |
+----+----------+--------+
```

I have these two tables and i want to calculate the total marks of student and my sql is:

```
SELECT SUM(`marks`) 
FROM `student_mark`
WHERE `student_id` IN 
  (SELECT `student_id` FROM `class_table` WHERE `teac_id` = '1')
```

But this will return `null`, please help!!

[DB fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xsY5wZJ8wctHBvpDLPyKMr/1)

Comment: What's with `student_id`?

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Firstly, you should never store comma separated data in your column. You should really [normalize your data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246701/what-is-normalisation-or-normalization). So basically, you could have a many-to-many table mapping `teacher_to_student`, which will have `teac_id` and `student_id` columns.
- In this particular case, you can utilize [`Find_in_set()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function.

From your current query, it seems that you are trying to getting total marks for a teacher (summing up marks of all his/her students).

Try:

```
SELECT SUM(sm.`marks`) 
FROM `student_mark` AS sm
JOIN `class_table` AS ct 
  ON FIND_IN_SET(sm.`student_id`, ct.`student_id`) > 0
WHERE ct.`teac_id` = '1'
```

In case, you want to get total marks per student, you would need to add a `Group By`. The query would look like:

```
SELECT sm.`student_id`, 
       SUM(sm.`marks`) 
FROM `student_mark` AS sm
JOIN `class_table` AS ct 
  ON FIND_IN_SET(sm.`student_id`, ct.`student_id`) > 0
WHERE ct.`teac_id` = '1' 
GROUP BY sm.`student_id`
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you want to know why, The reason it returned null is because the subquery returned as '1,2,3,4' as a whole. What you need is to make it returned 1,2,3,4 separately.

What your query returned

```
SELECT SUM(`marks`) 
FROM `student_mark`
WHERE `student_id` IN ('1,2,3,4')
```

What you expect is

```
SELECT SUM(`marks`) 
FROM `student_mark`
WHERE `student_id` IN (1,2,3,4)
```

The best way is it normalize as @madhur said. In your case you need to make the teacher and student as one to many link

```
+----+-------+--------------+
| id |teac_id| student_id   |
+----+-------+--------------+
| 1  | 1     | 1            |
+----+-------+--------------+
| 2  | 1     | 2            |
+----+-------+--------------+
| 3  | 1     | 3            |
+----+-------+--------------+
| 4  | 1     | 4            |
+----+-------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter your table based on a comma separated list with ID, my approach is to
append extra commas at the beginning and at the end of a list as well as at the beginning and at the end of an ID, eg.
`1` becomes `,1,` and list would become `,1,2,3,4,`. The reason for that is to avoid ambigious matches like 1 matches 21 or 12 in a list.

Also, `EXISTS` is well-suited in that situation, which together with `INSTR` function should work:

```
SELECT SUM(`marks`) 
FROM `student_mark` sm
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM `class_table` 
             WHERE `teac_id` = '1' AND
             INSTR(CONCAT(',', student_id, ','), CONCAT(',', sm.student_id, ',')) > 0)
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xsY5wZJ8wctHBvpDLPyKMr/0)

**BUT** you shouldn't store related IDs in one cell as comma separated list - it should be foreign key column to form proper relation. Joins would become trivial then.