# Array of foreign keys in one column

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have two different types of objects, let’s say **event** and **person**. Each person can attend multiple events. I want to have two tables

```
event
- id      [int (4),primary]
- name    [varchar (30)]
- …

person
- id      [int (4),primary]
- name    [varchar (30)]
- mail    [varchar (60),unique]
- attends [Array of events.id]
```

Therefore, the field `person.attends` should be an array of integers of length 4 and I want to tell MySQL that each value in this array is a foreign key from `event.id`. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Instead you need a third table with event id and person id to define the many-to-many relationship. Putting some sort of list of values in the attends column like that is going to cause you problems in the future. (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: An **N:M** relationship is better modelled as a third "relationship table". Do that. Otherwise, you'll have a ton of headackes.

Comment: Modelling it as an array is not even 1NF.

Comment: First problem you're likely to encounter: how to select all people attending a specific event.

Comment: For more kinds of problems, read my old answer to [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to have bridge table for many-to-many relationships.

thus, add `PersonEvent` Table to your model

```
PersonEvent
- EventId      [int (4),primary]
- PersonId     [int (4),primary]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the proper way to proceed. You need to think in terms of [database normalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246701/what-is-normalisation-or-normalization) : you have a relationship between `person` and `event` where each person may have many events, and each event can have many persons. To model that
relationship,  you need a bridge table, like :

```
CREATE TABLE attendance (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    person_id INT NOT NULL,
    event_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY fk_person (person_id) REFERENCES person (id),
    FOREIGN KEY fk_event (event_id) REFERENCES event (id)
);

ALTER TABLE attendance
ADD CONSTRAINT attendance_pk UNIQUE (person_id, event_id);
```

The bridge table contains an autoincremented id, foreign keys that reference the 2 other tables, and a unique constraint to prevent duplicates.

Now, say that you want to list the names of all persons that participated a given event :

```
SELECT p.name
FROM 
    event AS e
    INNER JOIN attendance AS a ON a.event_id = e.id
    INNER JOIN person AS p ON p.id = a.person_id
WHERE e.name = 'The Foo Event';
```