# Table inside another table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I made a database called users in which it has a name, password and phone number, but I want this user to have another table that stores current_capital, current_percentage and current_date of that user but I do not know how to do it, some advice ?

I have the telephone number in the user database as the primary key.

It is advisable to have a database for each user? or better to these attributes (save capital_actual, current_percent and current_date) I add an attribute identifier_user that would be the phone number and put everything in a second table? (as records table)

Thanks.

Comment: Can a user have multiple current capital, etc. values? If not, then why create another table? Just add the columns to the existing table.

Comment: The current capital is updated day by day like the current percent.

Comment: Effectively, the user can have multiple current capital

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246701/what-is-normalisation-or-normalization

Comment: Shadow below you answer your comment.

Comment: Pls do not use answers to clarify your question. Edit the question instead.

Comment: Sorry I am new to the community!

Answer (score 0):

When using databases, you want to have a *data model* with a fixed set of tables and columns.  You then add data by adding *rows* to tables.  Not tables to databases, or columns to tables, but rows to tables.

From what I can tell, you have two tables connected using a foreign key constraint:

```
create table users (
    user_id int auto_increment primary key,
    phone_number varchar(255),
    password varchar(255),  -- should be encrypted
    name varchar(255)
);

create table user_daily (
    user_daily_id int auto_increment primary key,
    user_id int,
    current_date date,
    current_capital numeric(10, 2),
    current_percent numeric(5, 4),
    constraint fk_user_daily_users foreign key (user_id) references users(user_id)
);
```

Note that both tables have auto-incrementing primary keys.

Comment: Mmm ok, I'll put it in practice thank you very much!