# Helpful answer as the second post - sort order asc

Tags: mysql, sql

A forum has topics and in this topics are the posts. The sort order is from old to new. It is possible to rate each post with "helpful".

A default SQL selection looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `topic_id` = 5033 ORDER BY `post_id` ASC
```

The "helpful" field in the posts table has the name "post_helpful".

Is it possible to order the posts in this way:

1. First post - Contains the question
2. If a post with more then 3 "post_helpful" exists, display this post as the second post. **But only the post with the highest score.**
3. Normal post row without the second post id

I only want the post with the highest score on the second post position. But only if the post has more than 3 rates. If there is no post with more than 3 rates, keep the default order

Thank you

Comment: I don't follow your question.  Please add sample data which explains what you are trying to do here.

Comment: A bit outside the scope of the question as it currently stands, but you might be able to benefit from [normalizing your database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246701/what-is-normalisation-or-normalization).

Comment: @tim Biegeleisen My question is, How is it possible to display the best answer as the second post.

Comment: Again, please show us some data.  As of right now, any answer I might give you would involve a _lot_ of speculation, and you shouldn't leave people guessing here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sorry I would give you anything what you need but I dont know what exactly you are missing. Do you mean the normalizing of the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  The first part is a little tricky.  You can use multiple expressions in the `ORDDER BY`:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM posts p CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT MIN(p.post_id)  as min_post_id
      FROM posts p
      WHERE p.topic_id = 5033
     ) pp
WHERE p.topic_id = 5033
ORDER BY (p.post_id = pp.min_post_id) DESC,  -- lowest id first
         (case when p.post_helpful > 3 then p.post_helpful else 0 end) DESC,          -- helpful next
         p.post_id ASC;
```

EDIT:

To get the posts with the maximum helpful:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM posts p CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT MIN(p.post_id) as min_post_id,
             MAX(p.post_helpful) as max_post_helpful
      FROM posts p
      WHERE p.topic_id = 5033
     ) pp
WHERE p.topic_id. = 5033
ORDER BY (p.post_id = pp.min_post_id) DESC,  -- lowest id first
         (pp.max_post_helpful > 3 AND p.post_helpful = pp.max_post_helpful) DESC,          -- helpful next
         p.post_id ASC;
```

Comment: thank you very much for getting into. This is almost correct. Your query display all helpful posts > 3 to the second post orderd by as but the second post needs only the post with the highest score. I hope you can edit it.

Comment: @LarsVegas . . . Why wouldn't you want all helpful posts before the rest?  What if there are ties?  I modified the answer so those posts that are most helpful are after the question.  But there might be more than one.

Comment: Thank you very much again for getting into. I dont want all helpful posts before the rest. I only want the post with the highest score on the second post position. But only if the post has more than 3 rates. If there is no post with more than 3 rates, keep the default order. thank you very much for your time.

Comment: please read my last comment. I tried your query and this query works very well but now all helpful posts comes in the second position with the order from high to low helpfull but like I said, I only want the post with the highest score on the second post position. It would be great if this is possible.

Comment: what should I say. Awesome...it works like a charm now :) thank you very much. I have marked the answer as fixed. There is only one lil error, after the WHERE p.topic_id is a dot. This dot has to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to have more complex sorting for the query
Can you assign a value or weight by the count of rows that were flagged helpful 
This would then have a number to sort by

I.e. Query 2 counts the number of rows that show the post was helpful
Query 1 is the main query ordered by the value/count from Query 2

Comment: Each post in a topic can be rated as helpfull. I try to show the highest helpful post as the second post.