# Create a view which joins on a comma separated value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I request help for my homework in SQL.

I have a table with musical instruments:

```
id  instrument_name         instrument_at_shops
-----------------------------------------------
1   Electric Guitar         1;2;3;4;   
2   Midi Keyboard           1;3;
3   Tom Drum                2; 
4   Electric Guitar         1; 
5   Electric Guitar         0;
```

And a table with shops:

```
shop_id  shop_name  shop_address
-----------------------------------------------
1        Shop1      City1 Street 1, building 1                              
2        Shop2      City1 Street 5, building 4                              
3        Shop3      City2 Street 4, building 4                              
4        Shop4      City3 Street 10, building 7
```

In my musical instruments table I have several numbers which represent id's of the shops that have the particular instrument.

The problem is: how to create a view which contains a shop name and an instrument which is in this shop?

The logic is this:

```
SELECT shop_name, instrument_name 
FROM Shop 
CROSS JOIN Instrument
WHERE instrumet_at_shops CONTAINS shop_id
```

But I cannot create an appropriate query or view design.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5):

You should really put your effort into fixing the data model.  It is broken, broken, broken:

- Do not store multiple values in a string.
- Do not store numbers are strings.
- Foreign key relationships should be properly declared.
- SQL has lousy string handling functionality.
- SQL has a GREAT way to store lists -- it is called a table.

If you are stuck with a really, really bad data mode. . . . well, you should try to fix it.  But if not, you can use string manipulations:

```
select i.*, s.shop_name
from instrument i join
     shops s
     on concat(';', i.instrument_at_shops, ';') like concat('%;', shop_id, ';%');
```

Unfortunately, there is really no way to optimize this query

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, if possible, you should normalise your data.

[What is Normalisation (or Normalization)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246701/what-is-normalisation-or-normalization)

The most basic way you can do this, in your case, is to make the data in the `[instrument_at_shops]` column atomic, so it'll look something like this...

```
id  |  instrument_name  |  instrument_at_shops
-----------------------------------------------
1   |  Electric Guitar  |  1
1   |  Electric Guitar  |  2
1   |  Electric Guitar  |  3
1   |  Electric Guitar  |  4
2   |  Midi Keyboard    |  1
2   |  Midi Keyboard    |  3
...
```

There are other normal forms you can apply, which will help if you are dealing with a lot of data. But if this is the extent of your dataset, making these values atomic should be sufficient.

Once you've done this, you should be able to create a view with a lot more ease.

E.g.

```sql
SELECT      s.shop_name, i.instrument_name
FROM        Shop AS s
RIGHT JOIN  Instrument AS i
    ON      s.shop_id = i.instrument_at_shops ;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Gordon Linoff, you have problems in your data model, with multi-value attributes. But, with your current schema, below code will get you the result you need.

Go for normalized design, which will help in easier queries and better performance.

[dbfiddle for reference](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b4fb023c0e90f6219550dc2f0e624c2d)

```sql
DECLARE @instrument table(id int, instrument_name varchar(50), instrument_at_shops varchar(100))

INSERT INTO @instrument values
(1   ,'Electric Guitar',         '1;2;3;4;'),
(2   ,'Midi Keyboard',           '1;3;'),
(3   ,'Tom Drum',                '2;'),
(4   ,'Electric Guitar',         '1;'),
(5   ,'Electric Guitar',         '0;');

DECLARE @Shops table(shop_id int, shop_name varchar(20))

INSERT INTO @shops
values (1,'shop1'), (2,'shop2'), (3,'shop3'), (4,'shop4');

SELECT s.shop_name, STRING_AGG(instrument_Name,',') as instruments
FROM @instrument
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(instrument_at_shops,';') as t
INNER JOIN @Shops as s
on s.shop_Id = t.value
group by shop_name
```

```
+-----------+-----------------------------------------------+
| shop_name |                  instruments                  |
+-----------+-----------------------------------------------+
| shop1     | Electric Guitar,Midi Keyboard,Electric Guitar |
| shop2     | Tom Drum,Electric Guitar                      |
| shop3     | Electric Guitar,Midi Keyboard                 |
| shop4     | Electric Guitar                               |
+-----------+-----------------------------------------------+
```