# If you have a data object with large features (100+), is it better to expand this data by adding columns or by storing it in row format?

Tags: database-normalization

So, if you can imagine a person was simultaneously enrolled in 100 different courses and had just received final grades for all courses, would it be better practice to store that information like so (wide columns):

| personID | Math | Science | English |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 90 | 88 | 98 |
| 2 | 91 | 98 | 90 |

(and ...97 other columns)

Or like this:

| personID | Grade | Subject |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 90 | Math |
| 1 | 88 | Science |
| 1 | 98 | English |

This brings the columns down significantly (from 100 to 3).

Comment: You need to study at least the basics of [data normalization](https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-database-normalization-explained-in-simple-english/).

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246701/what-is-normalisation-or-normalization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creating 100+ columns on any table is always bad idea. there is limit on no of columns in any database.
read [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/database-normalization-explained-53e60a494495#:%7E:text=It%20is%20important%20that%20a,insertions%2C%20deletions%2C%20and%20updates.) to get better idea. as you can think of following way.

StudentsMarkDetails

| StudentsMarkDetailsID | personID | SubjectId | MarksObtained | ExamID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | 64 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 4 | 36 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 4 | 36 | 2 |

SubjectMaster

| SubjectId | SubjectName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Maths |
| 2 | Science |
| 3 | English |

Comment: Thank you -- but quick follow-up. What would the primary key look like in StudentsMarkDetails? Assume a person takes many more subject exams, so the personID column would repeat twice or more, would you just add a new index column that auto-increments, or what would the primary key be?

Comment: you can add ExamID in StudentsMarkDetails. so in that case StudentsMarkDetailsID would be primary key with auto-increment. check updated one.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely option two - few fixed number of columns.

The reasons are many. Here’s a few:

- maintenance: if you have 100 columns now, tomorrow you’ll have 101. Adding a column requires a schema change, which is painful
- access: to get a value, you need to code the column name. This a form of maintenance problem in the code that accesses it, be it queries or app code
- queries: basic queries become impossible. Write the query that returns the average grade for a student and the problem will be immediately obvious

Here are two solid rules I made for myself that I never break:

1. Prefer more rows over more columns.
2. Prefer more columns over more tables.

Comment: Also take a look at @Ganesh_Devlekar's answer's example. You can break your data down into three tables: (1) Persons - List of people, (2) Subjects - list of available subjects, (2) Grades - list of grades per subject per person. The Grades table has a reference to a PersonID and a GradeID in each row.

Comment: @adrian An FK to a Subject table is of course needed, but this answers the question as stated. This site is not a consultancy service - answers don’t need, and in fact should not have, all the details of a final grand solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to store the data with one row per person and per course.  Why?  Here are some reasons:

- Different people may have different courses.
- Most databases have a limit on the number of columns in a table.
- You may want to store additional information per score, such as the date/time it was entered.
- It is easy to add new courses or to change existing scores, if necessary.