# Prepared statement WHERE IN string returns only first row

Tags: php, mysql

I have trouble returning data in rows in MySQL prepared statement using string binding with commas as `WHERE` `IN` condition.

My string is as follows:

`$order_ids = '200,201,202';`

And here's my query statement:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("
SELECT id FROM TABLE
WHERE t.order_id IN (:order_ids)
");

$stmt->bindParam(':order_ids', $order_ids);

$stmt->execute();

while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
  echo $row['id'];
}
```

I'm supposed to get id 200, 201, 202 from the rows returns but it returns only the first row.

It works if I hardcoded the exact ids into the query statement without params binding, like so:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("
SELECT id FROM TABLE
WHERE t.order_id IN (200,201,202)
");
```

Comment: You could try [FIND_IN_SET(needle,haystack)](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-find_in_set/), it uses a string for the haystack. In my experience it's slower than IN but it might be a solution to your problem?

Comment: Try putting these into array like `$order_ids = [200,201,202];`

Comment: @shirshak007 that doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score -1):

does your table look somewhat like this?

```
    TABLE
================================
| id   |   order_ids| 
--------------------------------
| 1    |     200,201,202  |
--------------------------------
| 2    |     150,180,181  |
```

If yes, then it will not work because the `IN` in your case checks if `t.order_id = 200 or t.order_id = 201 or ....` and so on.
I would advise you to normalize the table, as explained here on [What is Normalisation (or Normalization)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246701/what-is-normalisation-or-normalization)

Comment: I don't think that's what Joe's table looks like.

Comment: @Dokik yes, it's exactly like that. I cannot change how the data is being stored, is there any way I can change the query to make it work?

Comment: @JoeS; what does your hard-coded version return then?

Comment: @JMP It returns all the ids in row.